# How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anchor, hashtag

Do any of you know how to nicely handle anchor hash linking in **AngularJS**?

I have the following markup for a simple FAQ-page

```
<a href="#faq-1">Question 1</a>
<a href="#faq-2">Question 2</a>
<a href="#faq-3">Question 3</a>

<h3 id="faq-1">Question 1</h3>
<h3 id="faq-2">Question 2</h3>
<h3 id="fa1-3">Question 3</h3>
```

When clicking on any of the above links AngularJS intercepts and routes me to a completely different page (in my case, a 404-page as there are no routes matching the links.)

My first thought was to create a route matching "**/faq/:chapter**" and in the corresponding controller check `$routeParams.chapter` after a matching element and then use jQuery to scroll down to it.

But then AngularJS shits on me again and just scrolls to the top of the page anyway.

So, anyone here done anything similar in the past and knows a good solution to it?

Edit: Switching to html5Mode should solve my problems but we kinda have to support IE8+ anyway so I fear it's not an accepted solution :/

Comment: I think angular suggests to use `ng-href=""` instead.

Comment: I think ng-href is only applicable if the url contains dynamic data that needs to be bound to an ng-model. I kind of wonder if you assign a hashPrefix to the locationProvider if it will ignore the link's to ID's: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Adam is correct on the ng-href usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anchor links in Angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026537/anchor-links-in-angularjs)

Comment: This is also an issue for new Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor

Comment: ng-href does not work for this usage. You will get the same result as a regular href attr.

Comment: @Rasmus - found this thread trying to solve an Ionic `overflow-scroll` interfering with $ionScrollDelegate - "...but then AngularJS shits on me again"  Made me laugh.

Comment: @rolinger Thanks for bringing this old crap to my attention again :D I still remember how frustrated I was with AngularJS at the time!

Answer (score 378, accepted):

You're looking for [`$anchorScroll()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

[Here's the (crappy) documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

[And here's the source.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/anchorScroll.js)

Basically you just inject it and call it in your controller, and it will scroll you to any element with the id found in `$location.hash()`

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
   $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
      $location.hash(id);
      $anchorScroll();
   }
});

<a ng-click="scrollTo('foo')">Foo</a>

<div id="foo">Here you are</div>
```

[Here is a plunker to demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCO051UJS8EHbdkmFV40?p=preview)

**EDIT: to use this with routing**

Set up your angular routing as usual, then just add the following code.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
});
```

and your link would look like this:

```
<a href="#/test?scrollTo=foo">Test/Foo</a>
```

Here is a [Plunker demonstrating scrolling with routing and $anchorScroll](http://plnkr.co/edit/De6bBrkHpojgAbEvHszu)

**And even simpler:**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    if($location.hash()) $anchorScroll();  
  });
});
```

and your link would look like this:

```
<a href="#/test#foo">Test/Foo</a>
```

Comment: Problem can come when you add routing: if add ngView each change of url's hash would trigger route reload... In your example there is no routing and url does not reflect current item... But thanks for pointing to $anchorScroll

Comment: I'm very new to AngularJS, just started tinkering last week coming from a jQuery background, so this may not the the "Angular" way to do this. However, it bothers me that the routing solution loses my controller's current state when (technically) only the routeParams changed. I fixed this by moving my data into a service I called "myData" that shares the data between the controllers and route loads. http://plnkr.co/edit/5AqcjbWCOQ6fhaiTH0T3

Comment: Come to think of it, I suppose it's better to just store the static data in the MainCtrl (hey, like I said, I'm new)

Comment: @WalterStabosz: You might want to look into $rootScope as well. It's a really good solution for persisting data between controllers.

Comment: @blesh, calling location.hash(X) changes the page since routing controls the views.

Comment: This solution causes my whole application to re-render.

Comment: @dsldsl && @OliverJosephAsh: $location.hash() will not reload the page. If it is, there's something else going on. [Here is the same plunk with the time being written out as the page is loading, you'll see it doesn't change](http://plnkr.co/edit/MuOY3mE1SfWAHkD1ijpk?p=preview)

If you want to scroll to an anchor tag on the current page without reloading the route, you'd just do a regular link `<a href="#foo">foo</a>`. My code sample was to show scrolling to an id on routechange.

Comment: @blesh: I'd recommend you also remove the hash after scrolling to the desired section, this way the URL is not polluted with stuff which really should not be there. Use this:

`$location.search('scrollTo', null)`

Comment: Is there a way to scroll using anchorscholl while compensating for a header that sticks to the top of the page? (Basically, anchorscroll with an offset)

Comment: @RichardJelte not directly, you'd need to add a hidden element, like an anchor or something that was next to your content with an offset, then scroll to that with $anchorScroll.

Comment: @blesh: How do i set the offset of the hidden element when the site is completely responsive?

Comment: @MohamedHussain you might want to post a question on this site, as I'm not completely sure what you're asking.

Comment: @MohamedHussain it looks like anchorScroll now supports a yoffset: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll#yOffset

Comment: As added in my comment to the solution by @lincolnge below, the hash-in-hash works great for me so long as I explicitly call $anchorScroll after a timeout. Seems like 1 ms is too small but 100 works nicely. Just dropping my tuppence

Comment: And if you are using hash routing (because you have to maintain something for IE8, for instance) setting hash explicitly definitely will retrigger location change events, and you get into temporal paradox hell where your doppelgänger screws everything up unless you litter your code with state-change flags, etc. But that's kinda normal in ng-world.

Comment: I found that simply passing the id to anchorScroll avoided an unfortunate page reload.

Comment: How would you make this work with Angular v 1.5.7? Currently, this way does not work on this latest stable version of Angular.

Comment: @BenLesh what is wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723741/1481690 after i prettify url it is not working second time

Comment: Hi sorry for reviving a dead thread. Is there anyway we can use anchorscroll from external links like Outlook email's link feature where if they click www.site.com/farm then it would scroll down to www.site.com/index#farm ? (since we can't use html or js or codes in outlook which means external links usage only) Thanks!

Answer (score 171):

In my case, I noticed that the routing logic was kicking in if I modified the `$location.hash()`. The following trick worked..

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    var old = $location.hash();
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
    //reset to old to keep any additional routing logic from kicking in
    $location.hash(old);
};
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that, the routing logic absolutely refused to behave even when using @blesh's .run(...) solution, and this sorts it.

Comment: Your "saving the old hash" trick has been an absolute lifesaver. It prevents the page reloads while keeping the route clean. Awesome idea!

Comment: Nice One. But after implementing your solution, the url is not updating the value of the target id.

Comment: I had the same experience as Mohamed... It did indeed stop the reload but it displays the hashless route (and $anchorScroll had no effect). 1.2.6 Hmmmm.

Comment: Thank you slugslog! This was a great solution to getting around the route reload.

Comment: I, too am having the issue of the `old` not working anymore. I am using `1.2.21` What I did was `var hash = (condition) ? 'uploadForm' : ''; $location.hash(hash); $anchorScroll();` and that worked. I am toggling a div. When it is visible, I wanted it to scroll to the element.

Comment: I added answer because I don't think we need to set it back just use .replace

Comment: Why not just `if($location.hash()) $anchorScroll()` with `href="#/path#target"`?

Comment: This works great.  Now it would just be great if we found a way to add the #target to the url.  Then it would be even better.

Comment: I use `$location.hash(my_id); $anchorScroll; $location.hash(null)`.  It prevents the reload and I don't have to manage the `old` variable.

Comment: Hey I gave this a go on angular 1.4x and it doesn't work :[  it stops the page from reloading but it doesn't scroll

Comment: Does all of this still apply to Angular v 1.6.0 or have things changed? I'm using ngRoute and trying to implement these methods and none of them work! It takes me to the proper route, but not to the correct hash location on the page :( http://stackoverflow.com/q/41494330/6647188

Answer (score 53):

There is no need to change any routing or anything else just need to use `target="_self"` when creating the links

Example:

```
<a href="#faq-1" target="_self">Question 1</a>
<a href="#faq-2" target="_self">Question 2</a>
<a href="#faq-3" target="_self">Question 3</a>
```

And use the `id` attribute in your **html** elements like this:

```
<h3 id="faq-1">Question 1</h3>
<h3 id="faq-2">Question 2</h3>
<h3 id="faq-3">Question 3</h3>
```

There is no need to use ## as pointed/mentioned in comments ;-)

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the solution here did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19367249/633107

Comment: Thanks for this solution. 
But target="_self" is sufficient. No need to double #

Comment: target="_self" is definitely the best answer (no need to double #, as pointed out by Christophe P). This works no matter if Html5Mode is on or off.

Comment: Great solution, worked for me. 
Note: if the anchor hasn't rendered the browser still won't find it.

Comment: Simple and complete.  Worked for me without needing to add yet another angular dependency.

Comment: This is the right solution. No need to involve angular $anchorScroll service. See documentation for a tag: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Although <a href="##id"> didn't work for me

Comment: @SamanShafigh you only need target="_self" and <a href="#id"> as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 41):

```
<a href="##faq-1">Question 1</a>
<a href="##faq-2">Question 2</a>
<a href="##faq-3">Question 3</a>

<h3 id="faq-1">Question 1</h3>
<h3 id="faq-2">Question 2</h3>
<h3 id="faq-3">Question 3</h3>
```

Comment: Awesome! By far the simplest solution, but any idea how to link to a an anchor on a separate page? (i.e. /products#books )

Comment: I think it is the same as the solution (/products##books) in AngularJS

Comment: From my experience, href="##" works only when $anchorScroll is injected.

Comment: This isn't working for me. It still replaces my URL, so instead of http://localhost/#/app/folder/250, when I click on the tab the URL changes to http://localhost/#tab-1.. so impossible to link to. If I try http://localhost/#/app/folder/250##tab-1 (as lincoln suggests) I get the default route instead.

Comment: this seems relatively simple but its not working :-(

Comment: I added  target="_self" and it worked like charm for all type of navigation within page ( read sliders, going to different sections and so on). Thank you for sharing this great and simplest trick.

Comment: I can only speak to my experience today with this (we are locked into 1.2.x so we can't pass an ID to $anchorScroll, etc) but using the hash-in-hash works for me. Consistently. **Only there needs to be a timeout for it to work consistently.**

Comment: Didn't work for me, I had to add target="_self" as per @Mauricio-Gracia-Gutierrez's answer below. Adding the ## was not necessary (didn't change anything)

Answer (score 20):

If you always know the route, you can simply append the anchor like this:

```
href="#/route#anchorID
```

where `route` is the current angular route and `anchorID` matches an `<a id="anchorID">` somewhere on the page

Comment: This triggers a normal AngularJS route change and is therefore discouraged. In my case it was very visual since the YouTube videos in the FAQ/Help page reloaded.

Comment: @RobinWassén-Andersson by specifying `reloadOnSearch: false` for that route in your routes config, angular will not trigger a route change and will just scroll to the id. In combination with the full route specified in the `a` tag, I would say this is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. I don't use any custom routes in my app, so doing a href="#/#anchor-name" worked great!

Answer (score 14):

`$anchorScroll` works for this, but there's a much better way to use it in more recent versions of Angular.

Now, `$anchorScroll` accepts the hash as an optional argument, so you don't have to change `$location.hash` at all. ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll))

This is the best solution because it doesn't affect the route at all. I couldn't get any of the other solutions to work because I'm using ngRoute and the route would reload as soon as I set `$location.hash(id)`, before `$anchorScroll` could do its magic.

Here is how to use it... first, in the directive or controller:

```
$scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
  $anchorScroll(id);  
}
```

and then in the view:

```
<a href="" ng-click="scrollTo(id)">Text</a>
```

Also, if you need to account for a fixed navbar (or other UI), you can set the offset for $anchorScroll like this (in the main module's run function):

```
.run(function ($anchorScroll) {
   //this will make anchorScroll scroll to the div minus 50px
   $anchorScroll.yOffset = 50;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you implement your strategy for a hash link combined with a route change? Example: click this nav item, which opens a different view and scrolls down to a specific `id` in that view.

Comment: Sry to pester..If you get a chance could you give my Stack question a glance? I feel your answer here has gotten me so close but I just can't implement it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494330/hash-linking-with-routing-anchorscroll-troubleshooting. I too am using `ngRoute` and the newer version of Angular.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't tried that particular case... but have you taken a look at [$location.search()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) or [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)? Perhaps you could use one or the other on initialization of your controller - if your scrollTo search param is in the URL, then the controller could use $anchorScroll as above to scroll the page.

Comment: By passing the Id directly to $anchorScroll, my routes changed from something like /contact#contact to just /contact .  This should be the accepted answer imho.

Answer (score 13):

This was my solution using a directive which seems more Angular-y because we're dealing with the DOM:

[Plnkr over here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sl2V4u3tVzsqEj7ttgNi?p=preview)

[github](https://github.com/khalilravanna/scrollTo)

### CODE

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('scrollTo', function ($location, $anchorScroll) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    element.bind('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var off = scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev) {
            off();
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
        var location = attrs.scrollTo;
        $location.hash(location);
        $anchorScroll();
    });

  };
});
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="" scroll-to="section1">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="" scroll-to="section2">Section 2</a></li>
</ul>

<h1 id="section1">Hi, I'm section 1</h1>
<p>
Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. 
 Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. 
Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. 
Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
</p>

<h1 id="section2">I'm totally section 2</h1>
<p>
Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. 
 Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. 
Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. 
Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
</p>
```

I used the $anchorScroll service. To counteract the page-refresh that goes along with the hash changing I went ahead and cancelled the locationChangeStart event. This worked for me because I had a help page hooked up to an ng-switch and the refreshes would esentially break the app.

Comment: I like your directive solution. However how would you do it you wanted to load another page and scroll to the anchor location at the same time. Without angularjs it would nomally be href="location#hash". But your directive prevents the page reload.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai with my directive, I'm not sure because I make use of the call to $anchorScroll which it looks like only handles scrolling to an element currently on the page. You might have to mess with [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) or [$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window) to get something involving a change of page.

Comment: You need to unsubscirbe from locationChangeStart event: 
var off = scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev) {
  off();
  ev.preventDefault();
});

Comment: Good catch @EugeneTskhovrebov, I went ahead and added that to the answer in an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set a hash prefix for angular routes `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')`

Full example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
      $routeProvider.when( ... );
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
  ])
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the outcome. It would be sweet though.

Comment: Are you sure. Why doesn't this work? If hash prefix is !, then hash routing should be #!page. Therefore AngularJS should detect when it is just a #hash, it should anchor scroll automatically and work for both HTML5 mode urls and hash mode urls.

Answer (score 5):

I got around this in the route logic for my app.

```
function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/search.html',
      controller: 'ctrlMain'
    })
    .otherwise({
      // Angular interferes with anchor links, so this function preserves the
      // requested hash while still invoking the default route.
      redirectTo: function() {
        // Strips the leading '#/' from the current hash value.
        var hash = '#' + window.location.hash.replace(/^#\//g, '');
        window.location.hash = hash;
        return '/' + hash;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angle due to: Error: invalid 'handler' in when()

Answer (score 5):

This is an old post, but I spent a long time researching various solutions so I wanted to share one more simple one. Just adding `target="_self"` to the `<a>` tag fixed it for me. The link works and takes me to the proper location on the page.

However, Angular still injects some weirdness with the # in the URL so you may run into trouble using the back button for navigation and such after using this method.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a new attribute for ngView, but I've been able to get it anchor hash links to work with `angular-route` using the `ngView autoscroll` attribute and 'double-hashes'.

[ngView (see autoscroll)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

(The following code was used with angular-strap)

```
<!-- use the autoscroll attribute to scroll to hash on $viewContentLoaded -->    
<div ng-view="" autoscroll></div>

<!-- A.href link for bs-scrollspy from angular-strap -->
<!-- A.ngHref for autoscroll on current route without a location change -->
<ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
  <li data-target="#main-html5"><a href="#main-html5" ng-href="##main-html5">HTML5</a></li>
  <li data-target="#main-angular"><a href="#main-angular" ng-href="##main-angular" >Angular</a></li>
  <li data-target="#main-karma"><a href="#main-karma" ng-href="##main-karma">Karma</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I could do this like so:

```html
<li>
<a href="#/#about">About</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is kind of dirty workaround by creating custom directive that will scrolls to specified element (with hardcoded "faq")

```
app.directive('h3', function($routeParams) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){        
        if ('faq'+$routeParams.v == attrs.id) {
          setTimeout(function() {
             window.scrollTo(0, element[0].offsetTop);
          },1);        
        }
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Po37JFeP5IsNoz5ZycFs?p=preview

Comment: This does indeed work, but it is, as you said, dirty. Very dirty.

Let's see if someone else can come up with a prettier solution, or I'll have to go with this.

Comment: Angular already has scrollTo functionality built in via `$anchorScroll`, see my answer.

Comment: Changed plunker to be less dirty: it uses $location.path() so there is no hardcoded "faq" in source. And also tried to use $anchorScroll, but seems due to routing it does not work...

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="/#/#faq-1">Question 1</a>
<a href="/#/#faq-2">Question 2</a>
<a href="/#/#faq-3">Question 3</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like to use `ng-click` here's an alternate solution. It uses a `filter` to generate the correct url based on the current state. My example uses *ui.router*.

**The benefit is that the user will see where the link goes on hover.**

```
<a href="{{ 'my-element-id' | anchor }}">My element</a>
```

The filter:

```
.filter('anchor', ['$state', function($state) {
    return function(id) {
        return '/#' + $state.current.url + '#' + id;
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution with ng-route was this simple directive:

```
   app.directive('scrollto',
       function ($anchorScroll,$location) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $location.hash(attrs["scrollto"]);
                        $anchorScroll();
                    });
                }
            };
    })
```

The html is looking like:

```
<a href="" scrollTo="yourid">link</a>
```

Comment: Would you not have to specify the attribute like `scroll-to="yourid"` and name the directive `scrollTo` (and access the attribute as `attrs["scrollTo"]`? Besides, without explicite jQuery inclusion the handler has to be bound with `element.on('click', function (e) {..})`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll).

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QeU4oPJ1f0tx5b0tyFFX?p=preview)

So the controller would be:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
     $location.hash(id);
     $anchorScroll();
  }
});
```

And the view:

```
<a href="" ng-click="scrollTo('foo')">Scroll to #foo</a>
```

...and no secret for the anchor id:

```
<div id="foo">
  This is #foo
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to make my Angular app scroll to an anchor opon loading and ran into the URL rewriting rules of $routeProvider.

After long experimentation I settled on this:

1. register a document.onload event handler from the .run() section of
   the Angular app module.
2. in the handler find out what the original
   has anchor tag was supposed to be by doing some string operations.
3. override location.hash with the stripped down anchor tag (which
   causes $routeProvider to immediately overwrite it again with it's
   "#/" rule. But that is fine, because Angular is now in sync with
   what is going on in the URL 4) call $anchorScroll().

```html
angular.module("bla",[]).}])
.run(function($location, $anchorScroll){
         $(document).ready(function() {
  if(location.hash && location.hash.length>=1)      {
   var path = location.hash;
   var potentialAnchor = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
   if ($("#" + potentialAnchor).length > 0) {   // make sure this hashtag exists in the doc.                          
       location.hash = potentialAnchor;
       $anchorScroll();
   }
  }  
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this works all the time, but in my application this gives me the expected behavior.

Lets say you are on **ABOUT** page and you have the following route:

```
yourApp.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'about.html',
                controller: 'AboutCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }
]);
```

Now, in you HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#/about#tab1">First Part</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about#tab2">Second Part</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about#tab3">Third Part</a></li>                      
</ul>

<div id="tab1">1</div>
<div id="tab2">2</div>
<div id="tab3">3</div>
```

**In conclusion**

Including the page name before the anchor did the trick for me.
Let me know about your thoughts.

**Downside**

This will re-render the page and then scroll to the anchor.

**UPDATE**

A better way is to add the following:

```
<a href="#tab1" onclick="return false;">First Part</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your scrolling feature easily.  It also supports **Animated/Smooth scrolling** as an additional feature.  Details for *Angular Scroll* library:

**Github** - https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll

**Bower**: `bower install --save angular-scroll`

**npm** : `npm install --save angular-scroll`

**Minfied version** - only 9kb

**Smooth Scrolling (animated scrolling)** - yes

**Scroll Spy** - yes

**Documentation** - excellent

**Demo** - http://oblador.github.io/angular-scroll/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

See https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.10/docs/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

> [reloadOnSearch=true] - {boolean=} - reload route when only $location.search() or $location.hash() changes.

Setting this to false did the trick without all of the above for me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Stoyan I came up with the following solution:

```
app.run(function($location, $anchorScroll){
    var uri = window.location.href;

    if(uri.length >= 4){

        var parts = uri.split('#!#');
        if(parts.length > 1){
            var anchor = parts[parts.length -1];
            $location.hash(anchor);
            $anchorScroll();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this will resolve the anchor issue.

```
app.run(function($location, $anchorScroll){
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On Route change it will scroll to the top of the page.

```
 $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
```

put this code on your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind @slugslog had it, but I would change one thing. I would use replace instead so you don't have to set it back.

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    var old = $location.hash();
    $location.hash(id).replace();
    $anchorScroll();
};
```

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) Search for "Replace method"

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution above works for me, but I just tried this, and it worked,

```
<a href="#/#faq-1">Question 1</a>
```

So I realized I need to notify the page to start with the index page and then use the traditional anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.15 and looks like I don't have to do anything special.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/provider/$anchorScrollProvider

So, the following works for me in my html:

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="page in pages"><a ng-href="#{{'id-'+id}}">{{id}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div ng-attr-id="{{'id-'+id}}" </div>
```

I didn't have to make any changes to my controller or JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime in angularjs application hash navigation not work and bootstrap jquery javascript libraries make extensive use of this type of navigation, to make it work add `target="_self"` to anchor tag.
e.g. `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#id_of_div_to_navigate" target="_self">`