# Is there a way of using routes in angular to automatically scroll to data within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to use routes like an anchor tag.

For example, say I had a category page with a list of products.

I wish to set the route `....../category/shoes` to go to the top of the page,

And `....../category/shoes/air-max` to scroll to the shoe on the same page that is dynamically loaded within a ng-repeat block.

Essentially, the page should emulate the behavior of a static page where:

- `/shoes.html` will go to the top of the page
- `/shoes.html/#air-max` will go to the anchor

the difference being that it is an angular app and the data is dynamically loaded.

Comment: yes. I'm using ng-view... see updated comments

Comment: Duplicate of [How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs).

Comment: It is slightly different. They are using hand written anchors. I wish to scroll to anchors generated using Ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You may use [$index](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) inside your ng-repeat directive, so that each item as a unique index.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in array">
  <li id="{{$index}}><li>
</ul>
```