# Link to a partof the page in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to link to another part of the page in html. normall this works like: `<a href="http://example.com/page.html#foo">Jump to #foo on page.html</a>` and it jumps to `<div id="foo">...</div>`, but I am using AngularJs. I believe because app.js captures the url, this is now broken. Is there an angular way to do this (e.g. ng-scrollto or something)?

Comment: here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs

Comment: Thanks, do you want to put it as an answer?