# ScrollTo function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll, anchor

I'm trying to get a quick nav to work correctly. It's floating on the side. When they click on  a link, it takes them to that ID on the page. I'm following this [guide from Treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/smooth-scrolling-in-jquery-quick-tip).
This is what I have for the scrolling:

```
$("#quickNav a").click(function(){
    var quickNavId = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(location).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

I initially placed it before the `</body>`. But I seem to be running into a race condition where that was firing before the quickNav compiled (it has a `ng-hide` placed on it, not sure if that's causing it - but it is within the DOM).

If I run that block of code in the console, then the scrolling works as expected.

I figured it'd be more effective to move this into the controller - or more likely within a directive. But I'm not having luck accomplishing that. **How can I get this block of code to work with AngularJS?**

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Here is a simple directive that will scroll to an element on click:

```
myApp.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, $elm) {
      $elm.on('click', function() {
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: $elm.offset().top}, "slow");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yz1EHB8ad3C59N6PzdCD?p=preview

For help creating directives, check out the videos at http://egghead.io, starting at #10 "first directive".

**edit**: To make it scroll to a specific element specified by a href, just check `attrs.href`.

```
myApp.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, $elm, attrs) {
      var idToScroll = attrs.href;
      $elm.on('click', function() {
        var $target;
        if (idToScroll) {
          $target = $(idToScroll);
        } else {
          $target = $elm;
        }
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, "slow");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then you could use it like this: `<div scroll-on-click></div>` to scroll to the element clicked.  Or `<a scroll-on-click href="#element-id"></div>` to scroll to element with the id.

Comment: Thanks for the help with a basic directive. I've made a couple very basic ones already. I'm not exactly sure how I would access the href within the quicknav (using a directive) to have it do the anchor linking.

Comment: I ended up removing several lines of code from your edit (mostly just the `if` block.) That would be used to scroll to an element clicked on (like you demonstrated in your plunker) correct? Just so it would be more modular?

Comment: Anyone managed to use this and get around the iOS 'feature' that results in having to double-tap to trigger a 'click'

Comment: @rnrneverdies it does work on firefox if you change $("body") to $("body, html")

Comment: For best cross-browser support, you should use $("html, body").animate()

Comment: How come I get "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" when trying your solution?

Comment: I'm not sure using href to pass the id is the best solution... I found it to be a bit jumpy as the browser tries to process it in a 'normal' way on click as well. The better solution in my opinion is to bind something to the scope, ie. { scope: elementId: '@' }, then <a href scroll-on-click element-id="#element-id"></a> and grab that in the link function instead

Comment: @Cory have you included/loaded JQuery?

Comment: says, $elm.offest is undefined. how can it be an undefined value.

Comment: @AndrewJoslin Your plunker example does not work at all for me on chrome on mac

Answer (score 33):

This is a better directive in case you would like to use it:

you can scroll to any element in the page:

```
.directive('scrollToItem', function() {                                                      
    return {                                                                                 
        restrict: 'A',                                                                       
        scope: {                                                                             
            scrollTo: "@"                                                                    
        },                                                                                   
        link: function(scope, $elm,attr) {                                                   

            $elm.on('click', function() {                                                    
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(scope.scrollTo).offset().top }, "slow");
            });                                                                              
        }                                                                                    
    }})
```

Usage (for example click on div 'back-to-top' will scroll to id scroll-top):

```
<a id="top-scroll" name="top"></a>
<div class="back-to-top" scroll-to-item scroll-to="#top-scroll">
```

It's also supported by chrome,firefox,safari and IE cause of the html,body element .

Comment: Why do I need two directives instead one `scroll-to-item=".selector"`?

Answer (score 23):

In order to animate to a specific element inside a scroll container (fixed DIV)

```
/*
    @param Container(DIV) that needs to be scrolled, ID or Div of the anchor element that should be scrolled to
    Scrolls to a specific element in the div container
*/
this.scrollTo = function(container, anchor) {
    var element = angular.element(anchor);
    angular.element(container).animate({scrollTop: element.offset().top}, "slow");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An angular solution using `$anchorScroll` taken from a now archived [blog post by Ben Lesh](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315005537/http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html), which is also reproduced in some detail at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717011) he contributed (including a rewrite of how to do this within a routing):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  var i = 1;
  
  $scope.items = [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }];
  
  $scope.addItem = function (){
    i++;
    //add the item.
    $scope.items.push({ id: i, name: 'Item ' + i});
    //now scroll to it.
    $location.hash('item' + i);
    $anchorScroll();
  };
});
```

And here is the plunker, from the blog that provided this solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/xi2r8wP6ZhQpmJrBj1jM?p=preview

Important to note that the template at that plunker includes this, which sets up the `id` that you're using `$anchorScroll` to scroll to:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" 
    id="item{{item.id}}"
>{{item.name}</li>
```

---

And if you care for a pure javascript solution, here is one:

Invoke runScroll in your code with parent container id and target scroll id:

```
function runScroll(parentDivId,targetID) {
    var longdiv;
    longdiv = document.querySelector("#" + parentDivId);
    var div3pos = document.getElementById(targetID).offsetTop;
    scrollTo(longdiv, div3pos, 600);
}


function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration < 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function () {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop == to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

Reference: [Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Andy for the example, this was very helpful. I ended implementing a slightly different strategy since I am developing a single-page scroll and did not want Angular to refresh when using the hashbang URL. I also want to preserve the back/forward action of the browser.

Instead of using the directive and the hash, I am using a $scope.$watch on the $location.search, and obtaining the target from there. This gives a nice clean anchor tag

`<a ng-href="#/?scroll=myElement">My element</a>`

I chained the watch code to the my module declaration in app.js like so:

```
.run(function($location, $rootScope) {
   $rootScope.$watch(function() { return $location.search() }, function(search) { 
     var scrollPos = 0;
     if (search.hasOwnProperty('scroll')) {
       var $target = $('#' + search.scroll);
       scrollPos = $target.offset().top;
     }   
     $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: scrollPos}, "slow");
   });
})
```

The caveat with the code above is that if you access by URL directly from a different route, the DOM may not be loaded in time for jQuery's $target.offset() call. The solution is to nest this code within a $viewContentLoaded watcher. The final code looks something like this:

```
.run(function($location, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
     $rootScope.$watch(function() { return $location.search() }, function(search) {
       var scrollPos = 0 
       if (search.hasOwnProperty('scroll')) {
         var $target = $('#' + search.scroll);
         var scrollPos = $target.offset().top;
       }
       $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: scrollPos}, "slow");                                                                                                                                                                    
     });  
   });    
 })
```

Tested with Chrome and FF

Answer (score 4):

I used andrew joslin's answer, which works great but triggered an angular route change, which created a jumpy looking scroll for me. If you want to avoid triggering a route change,

```
myApp.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, $elm, attrs) {
      var idToScroll = attrs.href;
      $elm.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target;
        if (idToScroll) {
          $target = $(idToScroll);
        } else {
          $target = $elm;
        }
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, "slow");
        return false;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion. One directive with selector.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" scroll-to="#catalogSection">Scroll To</button>
```

Angular:

```
app.directive('scrollTo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {

                var target = $(attrs.scrollTo);
                if (target.length > 0) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also notice [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Answer (score 2):

What about [angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll), it's actively maintained and there is no dependency to jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

very clear answer, using just ANGULARJS, no any JQUERY depends

in your html somewhere on the bottom `<back-top>some text</back-top>`

in your html somewhere on the top `<div id="top"></div>`

in your js:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name APP.directive:backTop
 <pre>
<back-top></back-top>
 </pre>
 */


angular
.module('APP')
.directive('backTop', ['$location', '$anchorScroll' ,function($location, $anchorScroll) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span class=\'btn btn-mute pull-right\'><i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up\'></i><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></span>',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function(event) {
        $anchorScroll(['top']);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to target div by using ID of the element

**Directive(Angular 1)**

```
angular.module("App") // Module Name
    .directive('scrollOnClick', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                scrollTo: "@"
            },
            link: function (scope, $elm, attrs) {
                //var idToScroll = attrs.href;
                $elm.on('click', function () {
                    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scope.scrollTo).offset().top }, "slow");
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!-- Click to scroll -->
<a scroll-on-click scroll-to="#scheduleDiv">Click here to Scroll to Div With Id ""</a>


<!-- scrollable / target div -->
<div id="scheduleDiv">Test scrolling ... You are able to view me on click of above anchor tag.</div>
```