# AngularJS - $anchorScroll smooth/duration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, anchor-scroll

Reading the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll) I haven't figured out if `$anchorScroll` can have a duration/easing option to smooth scroll to elements.

It only says:

```
$location.hash('bottom');

// call $anchorScroll()
$anchorScroll();
```

I do not use jquery and don't want to; is there still a clever yet simple way to make or extend `$anchorScroll` in order to make scrolling more smooth?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible using `$anchorScroll`. As you discovered `$anchorScroll` doesn't have any options and doesn't work with `$ngAnimate`. In order to animate the scroll you would need to use your own service/factory or just straight javascript.

For the sake of self-learning I put together an example with a smooth scrolling service. There are probably better ways to do this so any feedback is encouraged.

To scroll to an element you attach a `ng-click="gotoElement(ID)"` to any element. I think an even better route would be to make this a directive.

Here's the [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/).

**Update**

There are now a number of third-party directives for accomplishing this.

- https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll.
- https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll
- https://github.com/arnaudbreton/angular-smoothscroll
- https://gist.github.com/justinmc/d72f38339e0c654437a2

Comment: Very nice.  Here it is as a directive: https://gist.github.com/justinmc/d72f38339e0c654437a2

Comment: @JustinMcCandless how do you call your directive? I've tried:           <a ng-click="anchor-smooth-school('about');">About 1</a>
<a ng-click="anchorSmoothScroll('about');">About 2</a>

Comment: @Dan just do `<a anchor-smooth-scroll>About 1</a> <a anchor-smooth-scroll>About 2</a>`

Comment: Nice, i like this answer. But this still adds another reason to hate AngularJS, I mean, look at the size of this compared to JQuery scrollTo

Comment: Is there a reason jQuery shouldn't be used in this situation, or at any point while using AngularJS?

Comment: You can also check out https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll.  Extremely simple and only 9kb.  Also supports promises for `scroll end` callbacks and lots more

Comment: To use the directive, create an element with an ID (e.g. `<div id="my-div">my div</div>`) and then create a link like this: `<a anchor-smooth-scroll="my-div">visit my div</a>`.

Comment: After checking out angular-scroll, it seems like a better solution.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the angular-scroll, link "https://github.com/durated/angular-scroll/". It is smooth scrolling also few easing functions to get a professional look.

Comment: Does this plugin work on other elements apart form $documents? I tried to apply scrollToElement to a div so I can scroll a row inside it into the view, and it did not work..

Answer (score 10):

The answer from Brett worked great for me. I did some small changes on his solution in terms of modularization and testability.

Here's is yet another [working example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/6L7tA/) that includes the other version with testing included.

For testing, I'm using Karma and Jasmine. Signature has been slightly modified as follows:

```
 anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(elementId, speed);
```

Where element is a mandatory attribute to scroll to and speed is optional where the default is 20 (as it was before).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ngSmoothScroll, link: https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll.

Just include the `smoothScroll` module as a dependency and use it like this:

`<a href="#" scroll-to="my-element-3">Click me!</a>`

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions here actually does what OP originally asked, that is, make `$anchorScroll` scrolling smoothly.
Difference between smooth scrolling directives and `$anchroScroll` is that it uses/modifies `$location.hash()`, which may be desirable in some cases.

Here is gist for simple module that replaces $anchorScroll scrolling with smooth scrolling. It uses https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll library for the scrolling itself (replace it with something else if you want, it should be easy).

https://gist.github.com/mdvorak/fc8b531d3e082f3fdaa9
*Note: It actually does not get $anchorScroll to scroll smoothly, but it replaces its handler for scrolling.*

Enable it simply by referencing `mdvorakSmoothScroll` module in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Alan, thank you. If anyone interested, I formatted it based on John Pappa standards.

```
(function() {

'use strict';
var moduleId = 'common';
var serviceId = 'anchorSmoothScroll';

angular
    .module(moduleId)
    .service(serviceId, anchorSmoothScroll);

anchorSmoothScroll.$inject = ['$document', '$window'];

function anchorSmoothScroll($document, $window) {

    var document = $document[0];
    var window = $window;

    var service = {
        scrollDown: scrollDown,
        scrollUp: scrollUp,
        scrollTo: scrollTo,
        scrollToTop: scrollToTop
    };
    return service;

    function getCurrentPagePosition(currentWindow, doc) {
        // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        if (currentWindow.pageYOffset) return currentWindow.pageYOffset;
        // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
        if (doc.documentElement && doc.documentElement.scrollTop)
            return doc.documentElement.scrollTop;
        // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
        if (doc.body.scrollTop) return doc.body.scrollTop;
        return 0;
    }

    function getElementY(doc, element) {
        var y = element.offsetTop;
        var node = element;
        while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent !== doc.body) {
            node = node.offsetParent;
            y += node.offsetTop;
        }
        return y;
    }

    function scrollDown(startY, stopY, speed, distance) {

        var timer = 0;

        var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
        var leapY = startY + step;

        for (var i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
            setTimeout('window.scrollTo(0, ' + leapY + ')', timer * speed);
            leapY += step;
            if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }
    };

    function scrollUp(startY, stopY, speed, distance) {

        var timer = 0;

        var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
        var leapY = startY - step;

        for (var i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
            setTimeout('window.scrollTo(0, ' + leapY + ')', timer * speed);
            leapY -= step;
            if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }
    };

    function scrollToTop(stopY) {
        scrollTo(0, stopY);
    };

    function scrollTo(elementId, speed) {

        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);

        if (element) {
            var startY = getCurrentPagePosition(window, document);
            var stopY = getElementY(document, element);

            var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;

            if (distance < 100) {
                this.scrollToTop(stopY);

            } else {

                var defaultSpeed = Math.round(distance / 100);
                speed = speed || (defaultSpeed > 20 ? 20 : defaultSpeed);

                if (stopY > startY) {
                    this.scrollDown(startY, stopY, speed, distance);
                } else {
                    this.scrollUp(startY, stopY, speed, distance);
                }
            }

        }

    };

};

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of how to animate `$anchorScroll` . Here's how I do it in my projects:

```
/* Scroll to top on each ui-router state change */
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
 scrollToTop();
});
```

And the JS function:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        return window.scrollTo(0,0);
    } else {
        var body = $('html, body');
        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '600', 'swing');
    }
    log("scrollToTop");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use JQuery and Javascript with Directive to perform the scrolling to a specific div on anchor tag click.

Please check the working example on the below link -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67513880/6656918