# AngularJs - Scroll Top directive only scrolls when you hide div, not when it opens

Tags: html, angularjs, scrolltop

I made a directive that would scroll to a hidden drop down when "Learn more" was clicked. It seems to only scroll to the div when you click "hide" after it has already been open.

How can I make it scroll when it first drops down?

**Index HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="stuff">
<meta name="keywords" content="stuff">
<meta name="author" content="stuff">

<title> Title</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Custom styles -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/svg_style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!--Jquery -->
<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular -->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="index_body">
<div data-ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
<div class="top-header" data-ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
</div>

<div class="page [[ pageClass ]]" ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>

<!-- Main JS -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ResonanceCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ContactCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/LandingCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/SignInCtrl.js"></script>

<!-- Directives -->
<!-- <script src="js/directives/LandingAnimation.js"></script> -->


<script src="js/jq.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Template HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
<div class="caption">
     <h1 class="text-left h-color thin">
Text Header
</h1>

    <p class="lead p-color">More Text</p>
    <!-- Here is my Toggle Button --> 
<a scroll-to-item scroll-to="#myContent" class="lead p-color learn-button togglebtn shake shake-rotate" data-ng-click="isCollapsed1 = !isCollapsed1"> 
<small>
   <div ng-show="isCollapsed1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></span> Learn More
   </div>
   <div ng-hide="isCollapsed1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> Hide
   </div>
</small>
</a>

</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-6">
<img alt="Image" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/kip-animation.png" />
</div>

<!--Here is the what I want to collapse -->
<div id="myContent" collapse="isCollapsed1" class="row row-offset row-pad" style="margin: 0 30px">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="lead caption text-center">
         <h3 class="h-color2">Item 1</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
    <div class="lead caption">
        <p class="p-color"><small>Text</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="lead caption text-center">
         <h3 class="h-color2">Item 2</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="lead caption">
        <p class="p-color"><small>Text</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="lead caption text-center">
         <h3 class="h-color2">Item 3</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="lead caption">
        <p class="p-color"> <small>Some Text</small>

        </p>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- END DROPDOWN-->
```

**Scrolling Directive**

```
app.directive('scrollToItem', function() {                                              
return {                                                                                 
    restrict: 'A',                                                                       
    scope: {                                                                             
        scrollTo: "@"                                                                    
    },                                                                                   
    link: function(scope, $elm) {                                                   

        $elm.on('click', function() {                                                    
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(scope.scrollTo).offset().top }, 700);
        });                                                                              
    }                                                                                    
};
});
```

**App JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

$routeProvider

.when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'pages/LandingPage.html',
  controller : 'LandingCtrl'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/signin'});
});
```

Comment: What are the arguments to not use built in directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll ?

Comment: Because you cannot animate $anchorScroll. I want a smooth transition when the button is clicked. $anchorScroll just jumps to the ID.

Comment: Then why reinvent the wheel? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21918502/4573999 Does the example provided in jsfiddle in this post behaves differently from what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am not trying to reinvent the wheel. I have tried the those downloads, but I am still having trouble with them. When I click "Learn more" it does not scroll the window to the ID that I am targeting. Instead, it moves up not down. When I close the ID it seems to focus on it then. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Submitted code contains extra html which is not relevant but at the same time misses controller code to build a working set