# pure angularjs scroll event listener

Tags: angularjs

i'm using angularjs WITHOUT jquery, and trying to create scroll event listener.

tried this approach:

```
  $rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return $window.scrollY;
  }, function(n,o) {
    console.log('scroll');
  });
```

but it dosen't work..

I managed to achieve this goal using this technique to create resize listener:

```
  $rootScope.$watch(function() { // Listens to window size change
    return $window.innerWidth;
  }, function(n, o) {
    console.log('resize');
  });
```

is there a proper way to create pure angularjs scroll listener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

creating scroll event listener, 'The Angular Way', is actually very simple, using $window:

```
$window.onscroll = function() {
  console.log('scroll');
};
```

Comment: Awesome!! this is what i have been looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

try using ***onscroll*** event of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes. your correct AngularJs provide **$anchorScroll** to scroll across the page but not that much effective. You can either go top or bottom like this. If you want scroll at particular position across vertical or horizontal **$anchorScroll** doesn't have that option. You have to go for normal javascript even for animation also. If you would like to explore more in Angular Scroll [please have a look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749878/angular-js-anchorscroll-smooth-duration) Grate!!