# AngularJs scroll: how to "see" the scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I have this website in which I have a menu and onclick on the item I go to the section with that id.

My menu items are:

- Home
- Biography
- Curriculum Vitae
- Gallery
- Video
- Press
- News
- Contact

and my javascript is

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $location.hash(id);
    console.log($location.hash());
    $anchorScroll.yOffset = 50;
    $anchorScroll();
};
```

but how can I do if I'd like to see the "scrolling effect" while I go to the section? 
I mean, if I'm in the homepage and I click on Video, I would like to see my page scroll through "Biography", "CV" and "Gallery".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749878/angular-js-anchorscroll-smooth-duration

Answer (score 0):

You could add jQuery and use it to animate scrolling.

For example:

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
```