# Angular Js Accordion focus on item onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

hi I have this accordion and a vertical scroll, basically I don't want to get annoyed with the flexibility of height on my accordion so I put vertical scroll.

but my problem is I want to focus or view the content of accordion when I click its header.

this is what I had [image]

and what I want to achieve is maybe scroll to top or focus on content
[image]

could anyone help me this is the link to my fiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/MTKp7/110/) and my js code

```
angular.module("btst", []).
directive("btstAccordion", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
            "<div class='accordion' ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // give this element a unique id
            var id = element.attr("id");
            if (!id) {
                id = "btst-acc" + scope.$id;
                element.attr("id", id);
            }

            // set data-parent on accordion-toggle elements
            var arr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("data-parent", "#" + id);
                $(arr[i]).attr("href", "#" + id + "collapse" + i);
            }
            arr = element.find(".accordion-body");
            $(arr[0]).addClass("in"); // expand first pane
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("id", id + "collapse" + i);
            }
        },
        controller: function () {}
    };
}).
directive('btstPane', function () {
    return {
        require: "^btstAccordion",
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            category: "=",
            order: "="
        },
        template:
            "<div class='accordion-group' >" +
            "  <div class='accordion-heading'>" +
            "    <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'> {{category.name}} - </a>" +

            "  </div>" +
            "<div class='accordion-body collapse'>" +
            "  <div class='accordion-inner' ng-transclude></div>" +
            "  </div>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("title", function () {
                // NOTE: this requires jQuery (jQLite won't do html)
                var hdr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
                hdr.html(scope.title);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/MTKp7/110/)

Comment: Looks like same to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284005/scrollto-function-in-angularjs. (solution http://plnkr.co/edit/yz1EHB8ad3C59N6PzdCD?p=preview)

Comment: click do not do any with that plnkr