# How can I scroll a div on a page without using jquery (what is the "Angular way") and without scrolling the window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284005/#answer-28558546) to scroll a container to a certain position.  Here's my version:

```
var wrapper = angular.element(document.getElementById('myWrapper'))[0];
var container = wrapper.querySelector('#myContainer');
var anchor = wrapper.querySelector('#myAnchorWithinTheContainer');
scrollContainerToAnchor(container, anchor);

...

function scrollContainerToAnchor(container, anchor) {
    var element = angular.element(anchor);
    angular.element(container).animate({scrollTop: element.offset().top}, "slow");
}
```

However, `angular.element` returns an array, so I don't see how that answer can work... but even if I correct it to the following:

```
function scrollContainerToAnchor(container, anchor) {
    var element = angular.element(anchor);
    angular.element(container)[0].animate({scrollTop: element[0].offset().top}, "slow");
}
```

the browser will still complain that "element[0].offset is not a function".  So, I attempted to use `getBoundingClientRect()` instead:

```
function scrollContainerToAnchor(container, anchor) {
    var element = angular.element(anchor);
    angular.element(container)[0].animate({scrollTop: element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top}, "slow");
}
```

but then the browser gives me "Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': The provided double value is non-finite" (in my case, the "non-finite" value that it's complaining about is 3282.9375(?)).

Anyway, the fact that the above-linked answer has (as of today) 10 upvotes and no complaints in the comments suggests that I am missing something, not that the answer is incorrect... **So, what am I missing**?

If there's a better way to scroll a div without using jQuery and *without* scrolling the whole page in addition to the div (I've already looked at `$anchorScroll`, but it scrolls both the window and the div), I'm up for other suggestions/techniques.

Comment: have you included `ngAnimate` module and its respective js file?

Comment: Yes, ngAnimate is included.

Comment: jQuery isn't included, and I'm hoping to avoid including it.  Is there jQuery code above?  It looks all plain angular to me...

Comment: **what am I missing?** - jQuery! :) - But in all seriousness, if you're wanting a way to do this without jQuery, spending 95% of your question talking about an implementation that depends on jQuery is probably not the best way to go about it.

Comment: Does it work if you don't get element [0]? I might be getting confused with jQuery, but it's possible that that would work since AngularJS's version is based off of jQuery -[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Answer (score 0):

[The answer referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284005/#answer-28558546) requires jQuery. The [`offset` function](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is part of jQuery. Angular makes use of [jQuery Lite aka jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), which has no `offset` function.

To scroll the div without jQuery, I did the following:

HTML:

```
...
<div id="myScrollableDiv">
    ...
    <div id="elementIWantToScrollTo">...</div>
</div>
<div in-view="scrollableDivIsVisible()"></div>
...
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myModule')
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    ...

    var _hasBeenScrolled = false;
    $scope.scrollableDivIsVisible() {
        if (!_hasBeenScrolled) {
            document.getElementById('elementIWantToScrollTo').scrollIntoView();
            _hasBeenScrolled = true;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Note that `scrollIntoView()` causes both the window and the div to scroll (similar to `$anchorScroll`, but easier to use and doesn't add a hash tag to the URL).  Since one of the requirements is to NOT scroll the window, I avoid that by using the [in-view](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) directive to detect when the *bottom* of my scrollable div is visible.  Thus I only trigger `scrollIntoView()` when scrolling the window won't matter/is already complete.  Then I use `_hasBeenScrolled` to ensure `scrollIntoView()` doesn't interfere with any scrolling that the *user* did (i.e. it's only *auto* scrolled once).

If you need to scroll a div based on some other trigger, rather than when the user first sees it, as was my need, then you can use the in-view directive to set a variable and then `$scope.$watch()` that variable before running your other trigger.

Maybe there's a better "Angular way" to do it, but the above gets the job done, and doesn't need jQuery.