# Can the jQuery scrollTo effect be achieved with AngularJs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll

I am making single page website in which as soon as you click the tab it navigates to the respective **div** with scrolling. I found scrollTo jquery function for that. But my question is , is it possible to achieve the same effect with angularjs or is it possible to embed jquery inside angular code?

Comment: Did you check this? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284005/scrollto-function-in-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ScrollTo function in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284005/scrollto-function-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `scrollTo` jQuery function in Angular is the [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) service.

For example, the following code will scroll to the first element with `id="myElementId"`.

```
$location.hash('myElementId');
$anchorScroll();
```

### [Here is a demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V68vNiBwaaQe9RVou2lj?p=preview)

Comment: but how to change the tabs when the page is scrolling in angular js?

Comment: @Mrugesh What do you mean by "changing the tab"?

Comment: means, suppose I have three clickable tabs "x","y" and "z" .So as soon as I click "x" it should scroll to the divs related to x or when I automatically scroll to the div connected with x , it should show x highlighted