# how to scroll to the loaded ui-view

Tags: scroll, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-view inside of my page.
When some button is clicked, the ui-view is loaded and replaced by some HTML.
I want the page to be scrolled down to the just-loaded part of the page.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs/14717011#14717011

Answer (score 23):

The ui-router module has been updated to scroll to the ui-view by default. You can add the `autoscroll="false"` attribute on `<div ui-view>` to prevent this. The default setting is `true` which scrolls to the ui-view upon state change.

I would think it should be the other way around where you have to set the autoscroll to enable rather than disable but this is the functionality of the updated ui-router.

You can read about it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/715).

In the linked Github issue, it says that the default value is `autoscroll="expr"` but I have found that `expr` does nothing and that the default value is `autoscroll="true"` (which makes more sense).

Comment: Thanks for writing this.  This new update has been driving me insane, as all my pages suddenly loaded scrolled down, and I couldn't figure out why.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

On Route change it will scroll to the top of the page.

```
 $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
```

put this code on your controller. (Change the value as per your requirements)

Comment: I had to use `$stateChangeSuccess` but it worked well. Also used `$window` service for testability