# Page refresh issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a peculiar problem .I am using anchorScroll service to scroll the page to top to show any messages,like for error or save success messages. I am implementing the function in save button action.

What happens here that when I hit the button first time, it refreshes the page and then when I use it again ,I am getting the required result.

I would like to somehow stop it from refreshing the page first time around.

This button is outside the form directive,although my form is inside form tag.
    Included $anchorScroll service

```
<a id="top"></a>   at the top of my HTML page.

if(data.validateError==true )
                {
                    $scope.saveSuccessfull=false;
                    $scope.wrongInputError=true;
                    $scope.negErrorMessage=false;
                    $scope.loaderDiv=false;
                    $location.hash('top');
                     // call $anchorScroll()
                   $anchorScroll();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935517/971 which proved useful to me having a similar issue.

```
var old = $location.hash();
$location.hash('top');
$anchorScroll();
//reset to old to keep any additional routing logic from kicking in
$location.hash(old);
```

This will prevent the reload.

Comment: If only I could give you three up votes for this great solution. Was wracking my brain for awhile.

Comment: Why this is not in the official docs example, really annoys me. Was about to custom roll some JS....

Answer (score 3):

The reloadOnSearch: false solution suggested by @Raulucco worked fine for me. Following an example

```
$routeProvider
.when('/search', {
           templateUrl : 'views/search.html', reloadOnSearch: false
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer after having the same problem. I resolve it by creating a new service that makes the scroll with jQuery. but I found on the documentation that on the [routeProvider](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) is possible to set the attribute reloadOnSearch to false, so that now you can change the hash and the view won't reload. I found it a cleaner way.