# How to use native anchor links with angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using angularjs on a rather large flat documentation page. The page has some navigation thats designed to use traditional url hash links. The urls look like so:

`/documentation/flat#26166276-basic-events`

These urls get rewritten once the navigation occurs and i've hit the next page. angular initializes to something like: 
`/documentation/flat#/26166276-basic-events`

This breaks the navigation. It seems to work if I am already on the `/documentation/flat` path and hit one of the hash urls. It gets rewritten but the browser still focus's on the correct section of the page.

However if the the hash url is triggered from a different path the browser will not focus on the correct DOM element as the angularjs rewrite happens.

Edit: this is what the markup for a link looks like

```
<a href="/documentation/flat#26166276-basic-events">Basic Events</a>

<h1 class="chap-header" id="26166276-basic-events">2.1.0 Basic Events</h1>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: @JustinNiessner added a markup example

Comment: Are you sure the the URL is getting re-written in the tag and not by the page you are navigating to (after the navigation occurs)?

Comment: Sorry for clarification the url is rewritten once the navigation occurs it literally changes the url in the address bar of the browser

Comment: Then you may want to delete this and ask the question "How to make Angular play nice with other hash values?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic was further discussed here:

[How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

I used a variation from that thread

```
if $location.$$url[0]== '#'
        $location.hash($location.$$url.replace('#', ''))
        $anchorScroll()
```

that basically lets me prefix any anchor links with an additional `#` and angularjs treats them as traditional anchor

Answer (score 0):

There is a very silly solution: put a / at the start of the anchor id!

```
<a id='/my-id' />
```