# Can I reclaim control of the URL hash-fragment from AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url

I'm using AngularJS, and would like to process a given `#hash-fragment` in the address-bar. However, —and this is key— I'll *not* be using the hash-fragment to encode a path. But it seems AngularJS insists on interpreting it that way.

For example, when `html5Mode` is disabled:

- A given URL: `http://my.domain.com#my-hash`
- is turned into `http://my.domain.com/#/my-hash`, and
- `$location.hash()` will be empty.

And when `html5Mode` is enabled:

- A given URL: `http://my.domain.com#my-hash`
- is turned into `http://my.domain.com/my-hash`, and
- `$location.hash()` will still be empty.

AngularJS must be thinking: "oh, you have html5, let me remove that hash for you". How considerate…

The only way to get anything from `$location.hash()` is when the URL has a double hash:

- For a given URL: `http://my.domain.com##my-hash`
- `$location.hash()` is finally equal to `"my-hash"`, and
- if also `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` one of the hashes is stripped from the URL.

But I really need a simple single hash character to remain unprocessed. Is this possible?

Comment: what is use case? have you considered using `search` rather than hash?

Comment: It's the original use-case of the hash-fragment: I'm using it to focus attention on a specific part of the current document. `search` is too verbose and used for another purpose.

Comment: I don't think there are any easy ways to regain controls of #, but you have alternatives to focus on a part of a document, http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs , http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll

Comment: @EliteOctagon: I know there are Javascript ways to do this. In fact, I would use Javascript for this myself, because the particular kind of 'focus' I am talking about is not just scrolling over to some element. --- The purpose behind my question is to get nice, readable URLs. I have painstakingly designed a URL scheme for my app which requires the hash-fragment to be used for this purpose. --- (I may just have to hack into the AngularJS code.)

Comment: what happens when you grab window.location.hash?

Comment: @EliteOctagon: AngularJS rewrites `window.location`, which is basically the problem. `window.location.hash` is based on what AngularJS has set. --- When `html5Mode` is enabled it returns the same as `$location.hash()` (with a `#` in front if nonempty). --- When `html5Mode` is disabled it returns everything starting at `#`, including what AngularJS considers to be the path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`#` seems to work well enough on the angular api docs page. So with a little snooping and testing I found that

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
});
```

makes the difference.

Comment: Ah, the hashPrefix! Silly, in retrospect, that I never tried this. :-) It's not ideal, because that leaves one character that I can no longer use in the start of the hash fragment. But I'm sure I can find a character for which this doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: What if someone does not want to use html5Mode?

Comment: `hashPrefix` also applies in non-html5mode (which it has to be able to fall back on anyway, for non-html5 browsers), see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location for an example and further documentation