# How to enable navigation to a URL's hash with AngularJS's HTML5mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, hash, url-routing

I have html5mode enabled in my AngularJS application so I can access paths with the URL format `site.com/path` instead of `site.com/#/path`.

But navigation to a hash is not working properly with html5mode enabled. When I navigate to `site.com/#hash` through Chrome, the URL automatically changes to `site.com/hash`. Since `hash` is not a resource on the server, this URL results in the loading of the default index.html file instead of scrolling to the `hash` location.

This seems to be a very trivial use case but how can I make the URL format `site.com/#hash` work as expected with AngularJS?

Comment: Remove `html5mode` code and then try it

Comment: After removing html5mode, the URL needs to be `site.com/#/#hash` for the hash to work instead of `site.com/#hash`

Comment: if you add `#hash` it will not create any problem as it stays to client side only.Did you try to hit directly using same url on chrome address bar

Comment: In hashbang mode, if I enter the URL `site.com/#hash`, Chrome changes it to `site.com/#/hash`.

Comment: then enable `html5mode` then try hitting directly

Comment: Please note this html5mode behavior in the question: "When I navigate to site.com/#hash through Chrome, the URL automatically changes to site.com/hash."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with the help of:

- this StackOverflow question: [Can I reclaim control of the URL hash-fragment from AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268213/can-i-reclaim-control-of-the-url-hash-fragment-from-angularjs)
- and an indirect hint from the AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Quoting from the docs page:

> Note that removing the requirement for a tag will have adverse side effects when resolving relative paths with $location in IE9.

To summarize, Angular leaves hash-fragments in the URL untouched **only if**:

- html5mode is enabled,
- hash prefix has been set,
- and you have not set `requireBase:false` while enabling html5mode

No wonder people find it difficult to grasp AngularJS: the documentation is weak and the framework is like a magic black-box that takes control of your app away from you.