# Jump viewport to id using # symbol

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When using AngularJS, how can I cause the browser's viewport to jump to an element on the same page?

Without AngularJS, the following

```
<a href="#heading">Go to Heading</a>

<h2 id="heading">Heading</h2>
```

will cause the browser's viewport to jump to the heading if the link is clicked.

How can I make this work when using AngularJS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin for that called `ngScrollTo`;

you can try something like this;

```
<a scroll-to="section1">Go to Section 1</a>

<div id="section1">Section 1</div>

<a scroll-to="">Go to Top</a> </pre>
```

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngScrollTo 
And here is the working example;

http://jsfiddle.net/8Mtxc/1/

Comment: How can I change this to not scroll the element all the way up to the top, but to say 50px from the top?

Comment: you can create a div who's margin-bottom is 50px and point this to that div