# Link to #ID element from another page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried all the solutions presented here:
[How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

But none worked for me.

In my `header.html` I have a link: `<a id="button" href="#/views/home#page"> Contact</a></li>`

To an ID in `home.html`

When I am in `/home` it works, but when I am in another page it doesn't work.

I tried using `##page` with no success.
Or putting this in app.js:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
});
```

and customizing my link:

```
href="#/views/home/?scrollTo=page"
```

Can someone explain which files should I edit and how?

**Edit**: 
I started from [Angular-Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)

My `app.js` is:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.training',
  'myApp.faq',
  'myApp.media',
  'myApp.contact',
  'myApp.home',
  'myApp.apply',
  'myApp.classes',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/views/home'});
}]);
```

And in every view I have another js file like `training.js` which looks like:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.training', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/views/training', {
    templateUrl: 'views/training/training.html',
    controller: 'TrainingCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('TrainingCtrl', [function() {

}]);
```

It is configured based on angular-seed model.

So, when, I am in view `/faq` that has the partial `header` with the menu and all the links, how can I link to a specific ID in view `/home`?

Comment: Can you please explain what "when I am in another page" means?

Comment: @Dalorzo I mean when I am in another view other than /home, like /team.

Comment: Where is your routing config? can you share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you have the logic for scrolling to that hash in the `$routeChangeSuccess` and as the [documentation says, this event is](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess):

> Broadcasted after a route dependencies are resolved. ngView listens
>   for the directive to instantiate the controller and render the view.

So the view is not rendered yet, therefore the DOM element with that id doesn't exist yet.

Try putting that logic in the `onload` event of the [`ngView` directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) instead.

I've created this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/S7bUT8iYY7UEti71X5Z8?p=preview that shows that if you add that logic into the `onload` event of the [`ngView` directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) everything works fine.

Comment: @Claudiu mmmm, interesting, let me have another look at this... Also it would help if you could please setup a "plunker" reproducing this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have to create the plunker when I get home. thanks

Comment: @Claudiu this plunker shows that if you add that logic into the 'onload' event of the 'ngView' directive everything works. http://plnkr.co/edit/S7bUT8iYY7UEti71X5Z8?p=preview Please have a look at it and let me know if this solves your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, based on your example I managed to get it working. There were issues with the way I wrote my `ngView directive`