# How do I get angular.js to not over-ride another libraries functionality in regards to links?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hyperlink, angularjs-directive

I am trying to incorporate this script from the [Uikit](http://getuikit.com/docs/layouts_portfolio.html) library which helps organize images based on type. (Clicking on the nav above the images, will group them based on a specific type of your choosing) That link demonstrates how it should work. Now if you go to the [page](http://rustystark.com.s197090.gridserver.com/work) I am developing, you'll see the links seem to jump to another page.

I have tried to glean from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs) how to handle links but it seems to circle around in page links.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 11.15.2015**

I found this [article](https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/) which illustrates an approach on how to integrate a jQuery plugin in your Angular environment.

HTML:

```
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill" switcher="{connect:'#switcher-content'}">
    <li class="uk-active"><a href="#" >All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >App</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
rustyApp.directive('switcherContent', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).toolbar(scope.$eval(attrs.switcherContent));
     }
   };
});
```

But alas it didn't work. Clicking the sifter, still redirects me to the home page.

Comment: there is an `on('click',` event in this file - http://getuikit.com/docs/js/uikit.min.js that your demo doesn't seem to have.

Comment: I added that however I still get the reroute to the home page. But thanks for helping!

Comment: Try removing the href.

Comment: @ KG Christensen - So would it be `<li class="uk-active"><a "#">All</a></li>` for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `target="_self"` attribute to your `<a>` tags to bypass angular routing. Second suggestion would be try getting the photo library to make those links out of `<button>` tags instead of `<a>` tags.

Comment: Hey thanks Peter! I tried `target="_self"` but that didn't work.