# Angular ui-router change state on scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is an example layout. Assuming that section height is more or equal user's viewport.

```
+----------+
| Section1 |
+----------+
| Section2 |
+----------+
| Section3 |
+----------+
```

All these sections are placed in one view. And I want to change browser url dynamically upon user scrolls page and reaches one of sections: At first time user see `http://example.com/#/section1` (angular not using html5 mode), then he scrolls down a page and should see `http://example.com/#/section2` when `section2` element become visible at user's viewport. Also if user copies link, when he open i.e. `http://example.com/#/section2` I need to scroll page to that section.

To detect which section is currently is been viewed by user I use [angular-inview](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) directive.

Now I've done it through parameter:

```
$state.go($state.current, {
    section: $scope.activeSectionId // e.g. 'section2'
}, {
    notify: false, // do not reload page
    location: 'replace' // do not save as new history entry
});
```

But this way isn't quiet good and url are not looking friendly. Also it has a bug, when I click on a link with ui-sref, for the first time page jumps, changes inview section for some time and triggers code mentioned above, so actually it not navigates according to ui-sref. But next time I click - all works well (this happens just after page reloading).

Can someone suggest how to do this better, if it actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to change state, when you $state.go($state.current)? Maybe use anchorScroll instead, not sure about html5.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

EDIT:

Sorry, I missed about mouse scroll. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717011/1603188 and usage of $location.hash(id);

Comment: Usage of anchor scroll will not solve the problem to change state on natural scrolling with mousewheel, keyboard, etc. It will only change state on click on some link or button.

Comment: Yes, location hash could do the trick, but it produces another # in url and if I switch to html5mode it (hash) will also remain in url. My main goal is to achieve state changing and finally get rid of hash in url at all. But as I understand for now it's impossible to do this in clear way, so if no new answers appear, I'll accept yours, because it at least partially solves this issue. Thanks.