# How to use normal anchor links with react-router

Tags: javascript, anchor, reactjs, react-router

Very similar to [this angular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs): how do I use anchor links for in-page navigation when using react-router?

In other words, how do I implement the following plain HTML when using react-router?

```
<a href="#faq-1">Question 1</a>
<a href="#faq-2">Question 2</a>
<a href="#faq-3">Question 3</a>

<h3 id="faq-1">Question 1</h3>
<h3 id="faq-2">Question 2</h3>
<h3 id="fa1-3">Question 3</h3>
```

Currently I intercept clicks on such links, and scroll to the anchor position.  This isn't satisfactory, because it means it's impossible to link directly to some section of a page.

Comment: Someone edited this question into a totally different quesiton.  This is about [anchor links](https://www.google.com/search?q=anchor+links).

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well. They've said they "don't support this," which seems ridiculous when the product is a router.

Comment: @Mike - I'd be interested to hear your comment on my answer as I believe that should resolve the issue if you try it?

Comment: Your answer may be in this thread: [https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/770](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/770)

Comment: I ran into the same problem and solved it by intercepting the onClick of the anchor and using a scrollTo solution in place of the default browser behavior of the anchor tags. I agree with @Mike that this is rather ridiculous.

Comment: @CharlieKilian That's what I do currently, but it doesn't allow for proper linking...

Comment: @starwed I think what you're currently doing is the best approach with React, it's just not very typical to link like this - you probably want to take this to GH. https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/394

Answer (score 19):

The problem with anchor links is that react-router's default is to use the hash in the URL to maintain state. Fortunately, you can swap out the default behaviour for something else, as per the [Location documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/f7b86bc7c40c3e5167bf00c380405a69eb454b25/docs/api/Location.md). In your case you'd probably want to try out "clean URLs" using the HistoryLocation object, which means react-router won't use the URL hash. Try it out like this:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Comment: This is how my router was initially set up (using _Router.HistoryLocation_), but it doesn't automatically intercept _<a>_ links in either JSX files or content inserted with _dangerouslySetInnerHTML_. They've said on their Github issues page they don't support it and don't suggest binding events to handle it such as _$('a').click(func)_ which leaves me to question how exactly one is supposed to do it.

Comment: I think my need is different from the poster's initial question now that I think about it.

Comment: I get what you mean now though. I've never actually had this requirement so I just assumed it'd work but based on what you're saying it sounds like an extra workaround is needed, but that the HistoryLocation approach would provide a starting point.

Comment: There's a closed bug for React-Router around using HistoryLocation to enable Hash Links: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/394.  After it was closed others have posted it is still an issue, I find this to be true.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear from the answer or the comments - will this answer make an `<a>` tag correctly navigate to a section with a matching ID?

Comment: @Mike I think this use case is covered in [How to use React links when rendering content with dangerouslySetInnerHtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51569981/1804173)

Comment: @bluenote10 Thank you, but 5 years later almost everything has changed so I don't think my comment really applies anymore.

Answer (score 14):

[React Router Hash Link](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link) worked for me. Easy to install and implement:

```
$ npm install --save react-router-hash-link
```

In your component.js import it as Link:

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
```

And instead of using an anchor `<a>`, use `<Link>` :

```
<Link to="#faq-1>Question 1</Link>
<Link to="#faq-2>Question 2</Link>
<Link to="#faq-3>Question 3</Link>
```

NOTE: I used `HashRouter` instead of `Router`

Answer (score 7):

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Link using

`<Link to='/homepage#faq-1'>Question 1</Link>`

Then insert the following code inside your target React component (Homepage):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const hash = props.history.location.hash
    // Check if there is a hash and if an element with that id exists
    const el = hash && document.getElementById(hash.substr(1))
    if (el) {    
        el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
    }
}, [props.history.location.hash]) // Fires every time hash changes
```

Answer (score 5):

Using current methods you would use `Link` from `react-router-dom`

```js
<a href="#faq-1">Question 1</a>
```

would be accomplished with

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and using

```js
<Link to={{pathname: '/this-view-path', hash: '#faq-1'}}>Question 1</Link>
```

of course '/this-view-path' could be provided as a variable from your project

Answer (score 0):

For Router 6 use can use the following:

```
const {hash, key} = useLocation()
useEffect(()=>{
    if(hash){
       const targetElement = document.getElementById(hash.substring(1))
        targetElement?.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
    }
}, [key, hash])
```