# React router v4 active anchor link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I got ***anchor*** *links* in my app. How do I make active style work if `anchor link` is active.

```
<NavLink
  to="/#somewhere"
  activeClassName="selected"
>AnchorLink</NavLink>
```

Comment: What do you mean active style? Do you mean a purple link? This seems like more of a CSS issue.

Comment: @Li357 I mean if link is active - then "selected" class would be applied to it, but in react router in doesn't work with anchor link

Answer (score 0):

For styling current active link you can give styles to class that is provided in parameter `activeClassName`, but it does not work with hash URLs, but for active class we can compare `location.hash` with our hash name.

example:

```
<li>
          <Link className={location.hash == "#about" ? "active" : ""} to='#about'>
          About
        </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link className={location.hash == "#user" ? "active" : ""} to='#user'>
          User
        </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link className={location.hash == "#repo" ? "active" : ""} to='#repo'>
          Repository
        </Link>
</li>
```

So for this example we have provided styles

```
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

so font will be bold only for link that is currently active.

Comment: I'm talking about anchor link, not a simple one. Your example would not work.

Comment: Please show me an example with /#anchor-link  because in my case it's not working because location path is / and link is  /#anchor-link

Comment: I've got your problem, I find these sol for this.

1. https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456595/4591943

Comment: I've solved the problem of routing but I have not solved the problem of highlighting anchor link in the navigation bar menu

Comment: there is a hacky solution but it works for applying active class you can compare `window.hash` with link hash url