# How to use React links when rendering content with dangerouslySetInnerHtml?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm developing a blog page for a react application. The page is loading data from a CMS and the content of the blog post is raw html which I render on the page with:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}} />
```

However any links I put in the post like
`<a href='/'>Home Page</a>` don't use react router and instead trigger reloading the page.

Is there a way to handle this in react without having to parse the HTML and replace `<a>` tags with `<Link>`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a click handler on the HTML container to catch clicks. If the click originates from an `<a>` tag (or a childrn of), you can prevent default, and use the `href`.

In this case, you can use react-router's [**`withRouter`**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to get the [**`history`**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object, and to use the `push` method to notify the router. You can also edit the url, or manipulate it in other ways.

Example (uncomment and remove the console when you use the code):

```js
// import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class HTMLContent extends React.Component {
  contentClickHandler = (e) => {
    const targetLink = e.target.closest('a');
    if(!targetLink) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(targetLink.href); // this.props.history.push(e.target.href)
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        onClick={this.contentClickHandler}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}} 
      />
    );
  }
}

// export default withRouter(HTMLContent);

const content = `<div>
  <a href="http://www.first-link.com">Link 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.second-link.com"><span>Link 2</span></a>
</div>`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <HTMLContent content={content} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a small helpful tip: if you are providing relative route link like (/something) you can get that via `this.props.history.push(e.target.getAttribute("href"));`

Answer (score 0):

This will Work for you.

```
function makeUrlsClickable(text) {
  const urlRegex = /(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s<]+)/g;
  const transformedText = text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$&" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">$&</a>');
  return transformedText;
}

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: makeUrlsClickable(this.state.content) }}>
```