# How to transform anchor links from WP API into Next.js <Links> using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js

I'm using a headless approach for a React (Next.js) + Wordpress API app.

The problem I'm running into is when the content editor adds an anchor tag into WP's WYSIWYG editor. I'm parsing that content using React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and therefore a plain `<a href="whatever">` is generated.

How do I go about transforming that into a `next.js` `<Link>` tag?

Not sure if this helps, but this is a piece of my code:

```
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Page: {title.rendered}</h1>
            <div
              className="richtext"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content.rendered }}
            ></div>

            {wpData.acf.modules.map((mod, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={`module=${index}`}>
                {renderComponents(mod)}
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </React.Fragment>
```

Since I'm using a decoupled solution, the anchor tag points to the server url, which leads to a broken page.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so the solution I found was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51570332/11983936

Basically factored the content display into its own helper function and used that in the components I need:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import fixLink from './fixLink';

const useRenderRichtext = props => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleAnchorClick = e => {
    const targetLink = e.target.closest('a');
    if (!targetLink) return;
    e.preventDefault();

    const redirectThis = fixLink(targetLink.href);

    router.push(`/${redirectThis}`);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        onClick={handleAnchorClick}
        onKeyPress={handleAnchorClick}
        className="richtext"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props }}
      ></div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default useRenderRichtext;
```