# Display Links from text in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a tagging system where user can tag other users in the text with @ notation ,I am saving the whole tweet inn db ,but while retrieving I am getting a text displayed like this

```
Hi My first tweet<Link to='/userprofile/ron'> @ron</Link>
```

How to make it display like

```
Hi My first tweet [@ron][1]
```

where [@ron](https://link) is a link

Comment: Is there an option to change the way data is saved? If you can store the text without the `<link>` mark-up and just the `@name` instead, you could dynamically build those links when it's time to display the text (Which also stops old links from breaking if you ever change the profile URL path)

Comment: Can you give an example @DBS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569981/how-to-use-react-links-when-rendering-content-with-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
const text = "Hi My first tweet<Link to='/userprofile/ron'> @ron</Link>";

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />
```

**Note**: Make sure to import `Link` from `react-router`. Also keep in mind that this is risky due to potential XSS attack.

Comment: Perhaps  Sanitizing the text using the [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) module and render it using dangerouslySetInnerHTML would be better.

Comment: <Link > doesn't seems to work ,a href is working but it is reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

// 1. create component

```
let linkItem = (props) => <p>Hi My first tweet <Link>{props.name}</Link></p>
```