# How do I make an inpage link with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to make a React website and want it to use inpage links. I know that in normal html you can just use:

```
<a href='#someheader'>link</a>

<h1 id='someheader'>This is an example</h1>
```

In react though, I am using multiple separate files for each part of the website. So for the navigation bar I have a file and for the body I have a file etc.
I have tried the above technique, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is it because of the link and the place I want the link to go to are in different pages, or is it because of something else?

Comment: If you already use react-router, check https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/creating-a-hash-anchor-link-effect-with-react-router-a63dcb1a9b0e

Comment: If you are using `react-router`, the best possible solution I had was to assign a `ref` to the section I want to scroll to when clicking on the `Nav` and then doing `scrollIntoView`.

Answer (score 1):

**For this route:**

```
<Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
```

**## Link to anchor on same page**

```
<!-- AboutPage.js -->
<a href='#someheader'>Jump to someheader</a>
```

Go to anchor `someheader` on the current page (**Not** related to React-Router - this is simple HTML behavior). [a element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

**## Link to anchor on another page (Tricky)**

Jump to `someheader` point on `about` page.

This code will work (But you do not get the "power/features" of `React-Router`):

```html
<!-- HomePage.js -->
<!-- Simple href to anchor -->
<a href='about#someheader'>
  Go to about page and jump to someheader
</a>
```

But when using the `<Link>` component to navigate - the scroll to #hash will not work/scroll.
Related github issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394

```html
<!-- HomePage.js -->
<!-- anchor not working -->
<Link to='about#someheader'>
  Go to About page without jumping to #someheader section
</Link >
```

**How to solve this (True to Sep 20)?**

1. Use this  package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link
2. More ideas (Related/duplicate stackoverflow Q): [Using anchor tags in react-router 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4) // [How to use normal anchor links with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893855/how-to-use-normal-anchor-links-with-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Check out react-router which should solve your problem.

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Not exactly true. You can add `hash` to the URL by react-router (But the scroll into view will not work without some custom code). Read this issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394

Comment: Yeah you're correct. Missread the question. Thank you for mentioning that. Im trying to get my reputation up lol