# Go to link within same webpage in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink

I'm just starting angular and am able to display the homepage via the url: `http://localhost:8002/app/#/home`

Now, I want to use a name tag, to go to 'FAQ' section within the same page by using: 
`<a href="#faq">FAQ</a>` and `<section id="faq">` 
However, this is not working. Can anyone please guide me here ?

Comment: Could you add your route configuration here? And do you expecting that faq template should be loaded inside faq section

Comment: This is my route configuration: when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      }).  In my home.html, I have links pointing to different sections of home.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use $anchorScroll (better solution). You can see an sample and more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717011/4538695). I don't test ng-href but i think it is bad solution.

Comment: You can see an sample for the same problem in the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs/14717011#14717011

Answer (score 0):

You should write in the href attribute #/faq, with a slash.

and another issue, is using ng-href, as written in angular docs(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref):

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.