# Angular JS Scrolling to an element in another page

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I am building a SPA using Angular 1.4 and Grails. In my home page I have 3 sections namely section1, section2 and section3 with the same ID. I have a dropdown menu on the top and I have used the scroll-to plugin to scroll to the respective sections on click.

```
<li ><a href scroll-to="section1">History</a></li>
```

My Problem is that when I move to another route, the dropdown menu will still be at the top and I am not sure how to get this to scroll to that element in the home route from another route. This is what I have tried.

```
<li ><a href="#/home/section4">Economic Weight</a></li>
```

And in the route config I did this

```
      when('/home/:section', {
        templateUrl: '/euribron/js/app/templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      }).
```

and in controller I did this

```
    if($routeParams.section) {      
        var element = document.getElementById($routeParams.section);
        smoothScroll(element);
    }
```

But this does not work when I am on the same route and it does not seem elegant. Is there an easier way to achieve this in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scroll-to plugin, you can use **$anchorScroll** service to manage autoscrolling. Please see this post's answer [How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs#answer-14717011). Basically, you need to set $location.hash() to the section's id that you can get from $routeParams and call $anchorScroll() function to handle the rest. Use different id for the sections.