# Return to top button redirects to previous page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, href

I am new to AngularJS and I'm implementing two return to top buttons at the bottom of two different pages like this.

First page:

```
   <h1 id = "top">
    ..........
   <a href="#top" target = "_self">Return to Top</a>
```

Second page:

```
   <h1 id="top_second_page">
   ..........
   <a href="#top_second_page" target = "_self">Return to Top</a>
```

This works fine on the first page. But not the second page and just redirects to the first page. Maybe Angular is interfering with it somehow? Any ideas?

In addition, any link I have on pages other than the main page gets redirected back to the main page.

Comment: missing " after "_self in second page.

Comment: on that note, `target="_self"` is the default behaviour so you don't necessarily  need to state it.

Comment: @dmlittle  Thank you but for my actual code I had a double quote. This doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @NikhilBatra please see above

Answer (score 1):

Second page is missing a double quote on the end of target attribute.

Change

```
target = "_self
```

to

```
target = "_self"
```

Here is a previously answered question on anchor scrolling

[How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you but for my actual code I had a double quote. This doesn't solve the problem @BhavO