# Can I focus input elements when scrolling to them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I replaced my simple

```xml
 <a href="#id">Get notified!</a>
```

with calls to `$anchorScroll` during my transition to AngularJS as described in [Angular JS - Scrolling To An Element By Id](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html)  and [How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

This however has broken a nice feature. The href `#id` pointed to an input field. The new `$anchorScroll` behaviour scrolled to this element but did not focus it.

Is there a way to focus it? It makes this feature quite useless if I am unable to jump right to a field and start typing.
Edit: Ok, is there a way with AngularJS. I want to get away from plain old JS, as far as I can.

Here is a plunker that is taken from `$anchorScroll` docs, the target is now an input field, but scrolling to it does not focus it [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FIllgedtLmIGbEoFjwLl?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for focus element:

```
var el = $window.document.getElementById('id');
el.focus();
```

Dnt forget add `$window` service to controller;

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
// attach an onclick event for every anchor that you have:
for ( every anchor ){
    anchor.onclick = function(){

       var targetID = this.getAttribute( 'href' ).replace( '#', '' ); // or something similar
       var targetElem = document.getElementByID( targetID );

       targetElem.focus();

    }
}
```

NOTE: This is just pure JS.