# Skip navigation link for single page site

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, single-page-application

I have a site that is built as a single-page and all requests are made with AJAX.  The pages are like `site.com/#Page` or `site.com/#Page/Other`.

Now, I need to implement the a `Skip Navigation` link in the site, but because the URLs start with `#` I cannot use a simple anchor.  Is there any way to do it without changing all the URLs? Thanks.

**Note:** the skip navigation does at least 3 things: scrolls to that part of the page, focus on the element where the content starts (it can even be a not focusable element, such as an `H1` title) and lets the screen readers know about the change.

Comment: Are you using a SPA framework? It would be helpful to know details on how you handle routing. There's some [possible solutions for angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs) users, for example.

Comment: @Jasen No, I'm not.  I'm using a simple JS library for handling browser history, but that's it.  What I can see in the example you put is that it only scrolls, but doesn't work well with keyboard navigation or screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two things to do:

- have a focusable element (use tabindex="-1" for the elements which are not focusable by default like `h1`)
- focus it using javascript/jQuery `focus()` method

Example:

```
document.getElementById("myEle").focus();
```

or

```
jQuery("#myEle").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can take a look at `scrollTop()` in JQuery : https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: `scrollTop` only scrolls the window, it doesn't do the other things I've mentioned in the _Note:_. The main problem is that it doesn't focus on the element, so the screen readers don't start reading from there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I basically had to

1. Disable the framework/script used for handling the hash changes
2. Change the URL to point to the main content
3. Restore the original URL and re-enable what I disabled in #1.

For example, I had an event like this:

```
var onPageChange = function (newLocation, historyData) {
    // load page
};
```

First, I changed it to:

```
var pageChangeEnabled = true;
var onPageChange = function (newLocation, historyData) {
    if (pageChangeEnabled) {
        // load page
    }
};
```

And then, the `Skip Navigation` link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:pageChangeEnabled=false;var oh=location.hash;location.hash='#content';location.hash=oh;pageChangeEnabled=true;void(0);" id='skipNav'>Skip Navigation</a>
```

For easier understanding, this is the code in the `href`:

```
// disable navigation
pageChangeEnabled=false;

// save current hash
var oldHash=location.hash;

// update the hash/anchor, make everything work
location.hash = '#content';

// restore the old hash, as there are no elements that have the same
// name of the URL, it works
location.hash = oldHash;

// re-enable page navigation
pageChangeEnabled=true;

// void(0); is just to avoid the navigation of the link
void(0);
```

UPDATE: As explained by Adam, this does not fully work as keyboard navigation does not change. I ended up doing: `$('#content').attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();`

Comment: this won't give keyboard focus to the element. (pressing tab will lead you to the very first link of the page)

Comment: @Adam you're right. I though I have tried your answer and didn't work.  I tried it (again?) now and it works perfect on Chrome with NVDA :) Thanks.

Comment: If you put this in a function and attach it to the link with `link_elem.onclick=scroll_top_function` it will be more readable and maintainable