# Angular 2: jump to a partically element of a page when loading the page

Tags: html, angular

I want to navigate from one page to another and jump directly to one control in the middle of the destination page. Normally, we can use a hashtag "#" follow with the name or ID of the control.

However, this method does work that well in Angular 2. I have tried method like 
[Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor). With that method, the url does end with "#myId" but the page doesn't actually jump.

Do we have other ways to achive this?

Answer (score -1):

Angular documentation project has AutoScrollService service. You can try to use it. [auto-scroll.service.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/800b1b060edfc05fde2172121a163a2e1c868ae2/aio/src/app/shared/auto-scroll.service.ts)

```
/**
 * A service that supports automatically scrolling elements into view
 */
@Injectable()
export class AutoScrollService {
  constructor(
      @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
      private location: PlatformLocation) { }

  /**
   * Scroll to the element with id extracted from the current location hash fragment
   * Scroll to top if no hash
   * Don't scroll if hash not found
   */
  scroll() {
    const hash = this.getCurrentHash();
    const element: HTMLElement = hash
        ? this.document.getElementById(hash)
        : this.document.getElementById('top-of-page') || this.document.body;
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView();
      if (window && window.scrollBy) { window.scrollBy(0, -80); }
    }
  }

  /**
   * We can get the hash fragment from the `PlatformLocation` but
   * it needs the `#` char removing from the front.
   */
  private getCurrentHash() {
    return this.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
  }
}
```