# Angular 2 routing to specific part of a webpage from one component link to another component

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

I have a link in footer that takes to the terms page but I want that link to take to a specific part of the terms webpage (3rd paragraph in terms).

Here is the code for `footer.component.html`

```
<a routerLink="terms">Terms & conditions</a> | 
<a routerLink="terms">Privacy policy</a> | 
<a routerLink="terms">Cancellation policy</a>
```

In `terms.component.html` is the place where i want the privacy policy link in the footer to be opened when clicked.

```
<ol start="3">
    <li>INFORMATION SUBMITTED THROUGH OR TO OUR SERVICES</li>
</ol>
```

What do we need to use for these to work? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor

Comment: @StefanLoKranDotti the link u provided is for single component but i have two components to route to

Comment: It has nothing to with the component. The router is doing the routing to the component and settings the anchor. It should work like described below.

Comment: i have added the methods in the component then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to @Rahul VV's answer i have edited component with event scrollIntoView below like this

footer.component.ts

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(s => {
      if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const tree = router.parseUrl(router.url);
        if (tree.fragment) {
          const element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment);
          if (element) { element.scrollIntoView(); }
        }
      }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the answer ,

and  `<a routerLink="terms">Terms & conditions</a> | <a routerLink="terms">Privacy policy</a> | <a routerLink="terms">Cancellation policy</a>`

Instead of just using . `<a routerLink="terms">Terms & conditions</a>`

use like this

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/terms']" fragment="terms"> Terms & conditions </a>
 <a [routerLink]="['/terms']" fragment="cancel"> Cancellation policy </a>
 <a [routerLink]="['/terms']" fragment="privacy"> Privacy policy </a>
```

page should be like

```
<ol start="3" id="privacy" >
     <li>INFORMATION SUBMITTED THROUGH OR TO OUR SERVICES</li>
</ol>

 <ol start="3" id="terms" >
     <li>INFORMATION SUBMITTED THROUGH OR TO OUR SERVICES</li>
 </ol>

 <ol start="3" id="cancel" >
     <li>INFORMATION SUBMITTED THROUGH OR TO OUR SERVICES</li>
 </ol>
```

Refer to the API for detailed descriptions and usage. - https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: @Johny_Bravo please refer this answer

Comment: do i need to import any modules?

Comment: @Johny_Bravo please use more content for each references (terms & cancel & Privacy ) then  only the browser will starts with that part

Comment: yes i have a lot of content but wen i clicked on the specific link it is not going to the specific part of the page

Comment: yes its appearing but its not moving to specific part

Comment: @Johny_Bravo Only RouterModule is needed

Comment: i figured it out by adding router events in the component I am able to move to the specific part of the page

Comment: am too having this problem what you have implemented to work this

Comment: This worked! Just added ```fragment="idOfTheSectionIWantToJumpTo"``` and all good. Very straightforward!