# Angular 2 navigate to element in *ngFor using interpolation

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

I am using Angular 2 and looking to set-up a page where the contents are displayed through an `*ngFor` loop, and the body is displayed through a separate div. These use interpolation to display the objects relevant properties. I would like the content to link to the relevant div in the body.

To display the contents in the left hand side:

```
<div class = "contents">
  <div *ngFor = "let disp of content">
    {{disp.heading}}
  </div>
</div>
```

To display the article on the right hand side

```
<div *ngFor="let disp of content>
  {{disp.header}}
  {{disp.body}}
<div>
```

This is similar to the query here [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)

However, as it is in an `*ngFor` loop dependent on content, abd uses interpolation, I cannot see a way to identify different divs within the loops as these are provided dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, as it is in an *ngFor loop dependent on content

Not necessarily, You can get the current index of a `*ngFor` in angular using the predefined `index` variable

So, we can set the links to point to `href=#content{{i}}` which is `href=#content0` for the first element, `href=#content1` for the second element and so on,

```
<div *ngFor="let disp of content; let i=index">
    <a href="#content{{i}}"> {{disp.heading}} </a>
</div>
```

Then we can create the content divs using the same idea,

```
<div *ngFor="let disp of content; let i=index" id="content{{i}}">
    <h1> {{disp.header}} </h1>
    <p> {{disp.body}} </p>
</div>
```

so the first div will have an id `#content0`, the second one `#content1` and so on,

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-loop-id-dt2wfu)

Hope this helps