# Angular 5 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

What Im trying to do is have a link on my homepage link to a certain section on another page.. so what I've tried is to `routerLink` to the page and then a certain `id` but Its not working I'm not sure even if this is how you would do this...

**homepage.component.html**

```
<img [routerLink]="['our-products/#element']" data-src="../../assets/img/product-logos/product-logo.svg" alt="Product Logo">
```

then obviously on my product page

```
  <div class="product" id="element">Content in here</div>
```

any help would be appreciated

**Edit**
I have since added `fragment` to the string like so

```
<img [routerLink]="['our-technology']" fragment="element" data-src="../../assets/img/product-logos/product-logo.svg" alt="Product Logo">
```

which does then make the url `http://mywebsite.com#element` ..but it doesn't actually take me to that part of the page..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the property 'fragment' like that :

```
 <img [routerLink]="['our-products']" fragment="element" data-src="../../assets/img/product-logos/product-logo.svg" alt="Product Logo">
```

more info [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

Comment: This doesnt exactly work as expected.. yes the url changes to http://mywebsite.com#element and goes to the product page but... it doesnt go to the section on the page.. any ideas?

Comment: referring to this response you have to do the scroll action manually : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor