# Angular 5 anchor did not scroll

Tags: javascript, angular

What I am trying to do is to create an anchor link. This link will navigate to a specific scroll point in my page. I have Angular version 5.

Html:

```
<mat-list>
     <mat-list-item><a [routerLink]="['/']"> Intro </a></mat-list-item>
     <mat-list-item><a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="mobile"> Mobile </a></mat-list-item>     
     ...
</mat-list>
```

In home.componets.ts:

```
export class HomeGrComponent implements OnInit {
    private fragment: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {        
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    try {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
        }, 1000);

    } catch (e) { }
  }    
}
```

I took this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor) but it doesn't work. Url is changed to

```
http://localhost:4200/#mobile
```

but it didn't scroll to my point.
Also in console there is an error:

```
Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null
```

What can be possible goes wrong? If you need some additional information please ask me to reply. Also it could be great the scroll navigates smoothly (optional).

Comment: Have you tried logging `this.fragment` in your timeout?

Comment: Yes the problem remains the same.

Comment: Well, what was logged?

Comment: when I put console.log(this.fragment); It gives me null.

Comment: You can remove the ngAfterViewInit and use `this.route.fragment.filter(f => !!f).subscribe(f => document.querySelector('#' + f).scrollIntoView())`

Comment: no it didn't work it shows me - this.route.fragment.filter is not a function

Comment: Then you Need to add the Import `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';` and better use `[...].fragment.pipe(filter(f => !!f))[...]` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html)

Comment: no I did that and I have the same problem.

Comment: Do you even have an element with id 'mobile' in your template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165633/discussion-between-vasilis-greece-and-markai).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Code:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.sub = activeRoute.fragment.pipe(filter(f => !!f)).subscribe(f => document.getElementById(f).scrollIntoView());
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if(this.sub) this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Working [example](https://angular-zgkxhu.stackblitz.io/) and [Code behind](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgkxhu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That is working. Do you have an idea where to put a code for a smooth scroll?

Comment: 1) in ngOnDestroy when I put a console.log message, it never appears I don't know how it works,
2) the first problem is when the page is refreshing with /#mobile it says Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null and on page shows nothing,
3) the second problem after the click, if I want to scroll somewhere else and then if I click again the same button, it didn't navigates me to the point,
4) scrollIntoView function it didn't recognize smooth command. Can I do in other way somehow - a smooth scrolling navigation?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not working is that `ngAfterViewInit` is being called before the `Observable` is resolved, and therefore `this.fragment` is null, so no element is found

```
ngOnInit() {        
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    });
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let interval = setInterval(()=> {
        let elem = document.getElementById(this.fragment);
        if(elem) {
            elem.scrollIntoView();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);  
}
```

Comment: There is a problem. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Just add another check for `elem` inside of that `if`

Comment: I did if(elem && elem.length>0) - but it still did not recognized the length

Comment: If it still fails on `length` then just remove that and test for existence of `elem`, i've updated the answer

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: first when I press an other navigation button it didn't work for the other button plus (second) when I scroll to page after click when I press it again didn't goes to this point again

Comment: The scroll will execute only once, thats why we used `interval`, if you need to listen for `url` changes constantly then you can take a look at @Markai answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **setTimout()**. So you don't need clearInterval().
You can also access the fragment with the help of the **ActivatedRoute**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
           setTimeout(() => document.querySelector(this.route.snapshot.fragment).scrollIntoView(), 1000);
}
```