# Angular CLI v1.6.8 Routing & Navigating

Tags: angular-cli, href, routerlink

I want ask some question about routing and navigating in angular CLI v1.6.8

In HTML, we can use:

```
<p id="my_id">Hello World</p>

<a href="#my_id">Link</a>
```

How to use it in routerLink? I can't use href because I want to make SPA

Thanks before

Comment: routerLink is a directive of Angular. You're asking a question about AngularJS, which is a completely different framework. It's perfectly normal to use href in an AngularJS application. And yes, it will still be an SPA, and the AngularJS router will deal with it.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I have lack of knowledge because I am newbie. I already try to use href, but my page refreshed, dont like when use routerLink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the router you are using, you can use [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for angular 1.X routing if you are using UI router you have "ui-sref" to use instead of href.

Comment: i am use angular default routing. @angular/router

Comment: then you can use simple href = '/someStuff' it will work !

Comment: Yes you can simply use href="#/someStuff", # will do the trick

Comment: Yes it work if use href, but if I use href, my page has refreshed

Comment: @HansStefanus is you're using @angular/router, which is a module of ANgular, you can't possibly be using Angular version 1.6.8, because Angular started at version 2.0.0, and is now at version 5.x. You really need to start by knowing the name and version of the framework you're using.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrong. I already edit the title. I use angular CLI v1.6.8