# Issue in Routing - Hash Tag - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to converting normal bootstrap template into angular website. I am facing issue in routing while navigating from one page to another like `About` to `Contact` vice versa.

The template already has below format which using some css for smooth scrolling with help of `hashtag #`.

**my app.compo.html**

Before : `<li><a  href="#header">About</a></li>`

after :  `<li><a  routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active" href="#header">About</a></li>`

```
<a href="#header" id="btp" class="back-to-top btn-floating waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom-btn">
    <i class="ion-ios-arrow-up"></i>
</a>
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', component: about, data: { state: 'about'} },
  { path: 'contact', component: contact, data: { state: 'contact'} },
];
export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { 
  useHash: true
});
```

After I hit **npm start**, its showing like below in my console

```
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-04-05T05:55:06.359Z
Hash: 0bace8e39ad063fd5145
Time: 3614ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 46 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This is my first attempt with angular 2. I am not able to understand official docs and other related threads for my issue.

kindly direct me to right way. if possible please share some plunker or stackblitz example

Comment: I cannot see the property `length`used anywhere in the code! can you add that information

Comment: @Aravind . apologize. i really dont understand what you mean about property.? can explain what should i do.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor

Comment: are u trying to redirect to a different page or point to the fragment (element with #) on the same page?

Comment: try useHash = false, useHash works when you are routing to a different page like this www.smth.com#about

Comment: @Akanksha am trying navigate to another fragment of my single page application . like this |home|about|contact|

Comment: let me try your suggestion and come back

Comment: @Akanksha can you pls tell how to form this <li><a  href="#header">About</a></li> after changing hash to false. this tag already having #header in it

Comment: @Akanksha is right, just set `useHash` flag to `false` and no need to change other `href's`... angular's routing is based on routerLink and router oultets. see this example created for you on slackblithz.. https://angular-hxzu3s.stackblitz.io/

Comment: @Manoj Shukla tried.. but issue still persisting.. can you pls show stackblitz code? not able see your code formation

Comment: Sure.. Here is the complete link... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxzu3s?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html&view=editor

Comment: plz lemme know if it's still not working.. !! Will try few more options. :)

Comment: i did some changes as you said. but its still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168282/discussion-between-manoj-shukla-and-worstcoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done without using `href hash (#)` functionality..

Here is a working example..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxzu3s?embed=1&file=app/app.module.ts&view=preview

---

One more way to do is, using `hash #`

Here is another working example..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ji6grr?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html&view=preview

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by removing href="#header" as it needs routerLink property only.
And need to add router-outLet where you want to load that component.

Comment: but if i do what your saying, how can call scrolling functionality . i have update my code.. pls see that. #header comes in two places