# Not a valid selector error when trying to link to a section within the current page

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, anchor

I'm making an FAQ page that has all the questions at the top as hyperlinks. When you click on a hyperlink you get directed to the part on the page where the answer of the question can be read. For this I am trying to use the solution provided here [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor) provided by Kaloyan.
The solution breaks for me at the codeline

```
  const element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment);
```

This gives the error `ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1' is not a valid selector.`. I can understand why i get this error because it is looking for a selector, and the input it gets is #fragment. Yet everyone in the stackoverflow thread i've mentioned says it works so maybe i am doing something wrong. When i replace querySelector with getElementById(tree.fragment) i no longer get errors but the page does not jump to the section when i click on one of the links either. Can someone tell me what part i'm doing wrong or what part i've missed implementing from the solutions at the thread mentioned? Thank you.

Heres my code:

Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FaqItem } from './faq-item.model';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-faq',
  templateUrl: './faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./faq.component.css']
})
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {

  faqItems: FaqItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;



  constructor(router: Router) {

    router.events.subscribe(s => {
      if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const tree = router.parseUrl(router.url);
        if (tree.fragment) {
          const element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment);
          // const element = document.getElementById(tree.fragment);
          if (element) { element.scrollIntoView(true); }
        }
      }
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

const EXAMPLE_DATA: FaqItem[] = [
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},

    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},  {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},
    {id: 1, question: 'How do i use the seedcalendar app?', answer: 'please check the getting started tutorial for this'},

]
export class FaqItem {
    id: number;
    question: string;
    answer: string;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<section id="top">
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let item of faqItems; let i=index">
        <a [routerLink]="['.']" fragment={{i}}>{{item.question}}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
<dl>
  <app-faq-item *ngFor="let item of faqItems; let i=index" 
  [question]="item.question" [answer]="item.answer" [attr.id]="i">
</app-faq-item>
</dl>
</section>
```

Comment: Just an advice : It is better to subscribe to router events (or any angular events)  inside `ngOnInit()` rather than `constructor`.

Comment: If you `console.log(tree.fragment)`, what is printed to the console?

Comment: @user184994 It is probably 1 because error says `'#1' is not a valid selector`

Comment: @AmitChigadani Oops, I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand using [`fragment`](https://angular.io/guide/router#routerlink-binding) for anchor links (I could be wrong) is that they are used when navigating between routes and you wish to take the user to a certain point on the page once you have navigated there.

Your question seems to indicate that you are rather looking to click a link on a page and scroll the user to a corresponding section.

If this is accurate, you could just use [`@ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren):

---

add a templateRef (`#answers`):

```
<app-faq-item #answers *ngFor="let item of faqItems; let i=index" [...] [...]>
```

and a click handler to a question:

```
<a href="javascript:;" (click)="scrollTo(i)">{{item.question}}</a>
```

and in your component, use `ViewChildren` to get the current element:

```
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {

  faqItems: FaqItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  @ViewChildren('answers', { read: ViewContainerRef }) answers;

  scrollTo(index: number) {
    const element = this.answers.toArray()[index].element.nativeElement;
    element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior:"smooth",
      block: "start", 
      inline: "nearest"
    });
  }
```

---

Here is [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcmgbu).