# Navigate back to specific section of Previous page - Angular Router

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have 2 pages. Page1 and Page2. Page 1 and Page 2 are in different components.

Page1 have 2 sections.

From Page1, 2nd section using router.navigate(), I navigate to Page2.

From Page2 using location.back(), I can able to come back to Page1.

Using Location.back() always redirects me to 1st section of Page1. But I wanted me to comeback 2nd section of Page1.

Comment: I think this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor) on page anchor already answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a page anchor and it is supported by angular router, see: [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)
But I don't know if "location.back()" works with that solution. You have to test that or use a custom "back" navigation with router.navigate().

Else you have different other options:

- You can seperate Page 1 into two Subcomponents, one for each Section and with its own Route. Think about your app design if it would make more sense. This might be the simplest option and location.back() will work in this case.
- You can use an optional route parameter "page1?section=2" and search for it inside your Page1 component with the following code:

Snipped:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const section = params["section"];
   });    
}
```

Then you can scroll your view inside the Page1 component depending on the section constant. If it is equal to 1, you scroll to section 1, if it is equal to 2, you scroll to section 2.