# Angular 6 link to section in other component?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I have a navbar component with this code:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Inicio <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Here Link Home Section 2 <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
              </li>


</ul>
```

and have another component HomeComponent with 3 sections:

```
<section id="home_one">
    stuff 
    section
    one
</section>

<section id="home_two">
   stuff 
   section
   two
</section>

<section id="home_three">
    stuff 
    section
    three
</section>
```

How can I link from navbar links to specific section (section 2) in another component (homeComponent)?

Comment: Had you have a look ar Angular routes? 
You need to implement them in this case

Comment: I am able to make it work with routerLink="/home" an it redirects to the component html, but I WANT to route to SPECIFIC section... how can I do this? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular 6.1 has new featured called anchorScrolling, Enable this option and use Router fragement

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  })],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, ComponentbComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['item']" [fragment]="'section2'">
    section2
</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgmsuw

Answer (score 0):

## If this is onclick of tabs and changing of corresponding section of tabs:-

### .ts

```
tab = 'tab0';
```

### .html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
<li class="nav-item active" (click)='tab = "tab0"'>
<a class="nav-link" href="#" >Inicio <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item active" (click)='tab = "tab1"'>
 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Here Link Home Section 2 <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
</li>
 </ul>


<section id="home_one" *ngIf="tab ==='tab0'">
stuff 
section
one
// Here you can pass selctor of a separate component for each section
// <tab0-component></tab0-component>
    </section>

    <section id="home_two" *ngIf="tab ==='tab1'">
       stuff 
       section
       two
    </section>

    <section id="home_three" *ngIf="tab ==='tab2'">
        stuff 
        section
        three
    </section>
```

## If you want to go to corresponding fragment onclick ie to scrollview in that document:-

[Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)

## If you want to change routes for each tab then:-

### app.routing.ts

```
// create routes for each tab
```

### .ts

```
constructor(public router:Router){
}

opentab(routes){
this.router.navigate[routes]
}
```

### .html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active" (click)= 'opentab("tab0")'>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Inicio <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active" (click)= 'opentab("tab1")'>
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Here Link Home Section 2 <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
    </li>
     </ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In an angular way Its better for you to use Angular Router

Create Three components Instead of Sections

```
home_one
home_two
home_three
```

Then In your App Module Or in Seperate Routing Module declare you routes like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home_one', component: home_one},
  { path: 'home_two', component: home_two },
  { path: 'home_three', component: home_three }
  { path: '', component: home }
  { path: '*', component: home }
];
```

Then In your Imports add routes

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
})
```

Then In you 'Home page' or where ever you want to Render these sections Add Router Outlet, It will be something like this

```
<your-navbar-component></your-navbar-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In Your navbar configure your Anchor for your routes properly

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
              <li class="nav-item "  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home_one']" >Home One <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
              </li>
          <li class="nav-item "  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home_two']" >Home Two<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item "  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home_three']" >Home Three<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
              </li>

</ul>
```

For more Visit Official documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/router