# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /service-details/1139#overview Angular 5

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-routing

I am doing simple routing in angular. It is working fine but when I want client side routing means use of nav tabs to move in a same page then it is throwing an error. Here is my code :

**service-detail.component.html**

```
 <ul class="asidemenu">
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/service-details',serviceId]" fragment="overview" (click)="onAnchorClick()" class="
              active"><span
                class="asidemenu-icon"><img src="assets/images/binoculars.svg" alt=""></span><span class="asidemenu-title">Overview</span></a></li>
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/service-details',serviceId]" fragment="review-analytics" (click)="onAnchorClick()"><span
                class="asidemenu-icon"><img src="assets/images/graph-analysis.svg" alt=""></span><span class="asidemenu-title">Sentiment</span></a></li>
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/service-details',serviceId]" fragment="expert-review" (click)="onAnchorClick()"><span
                class="asidemenu-icon"><img src="assets/images/review.svg" alt=""></span><span class="asidemenu-title">Expert
                Reviews</span></a></li>
    <ul>

<div id='overview'> Overview (Removed Original content)</div>
<div id='review-analytics'> Reviews (Removed Original content)</div>
<div id='expert-review'> Expert Reviews (Removed Original content)</div>
```

as per above code I can move in same page freely but this error occurs `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /service-details/1139#overview` every time.

May be this is routing issue then how to fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did u add path for routermodule https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dymkil?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes but like this   {
    path: 'service-details/:id',
    component: ServiceDetailsComponent
  },

Comment: Don't know what to do with hash part @SachilaRanawaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `anchorScrolling` option where you import `RouterModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    })
  ],
})
...
```

More Info:
https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/introduce-router-scroller-in-angular-v6-1-ef34278461e9

Comment: I am using angular 5 not 6 so it is not working in 5 @zmag

Comment: @Aarsh This might be helpful : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44203337/3870547](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44203337/3870547)

Comment: Yahh I used that already but gives the same error in the end :-|

Answer (score 1):

have set {useHash: true} in routes definition

Comment: I can't because i have to use PathLocationStrategy can't use HashLocationStrategy

Comment: you can use fragment with # only in HashLocationStrategy

Comment: Yes I know it worked very well but in this project we have to use pathlocationstrategy otherwise it was working when we were using HashLocationStrategy

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want to achieve with this so that i can find some other solution for you, as i understand if you have # in your path and have PathLocationStrategy then you will get the syntax error

Comment: As I mention in que that I want to navigate in same page using anchor tabs without using hashlocationstrategy. Use # only on anchor tags where you want to navigate in same page other wise no #

Comment: "navigate in same page using anchor tabs" does it means that you want to reload the component or scrolling down to some other content in the page what exactly you want to do by navigating to same page prefer executing a function on click of anchor tag as fragment will not be allowed

Comment: scrolling down to some other content in the page not reload the component