# Cannot navigate to an html inner element with href=#id , in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, angular6

Im using scrollspy in angular6 along with uiRouter for routing now i cannot navigate to an html inner element with href=#id, it is going into url not going to particular div.

i have defined if any wrong url redirect to home in appmodule.ts as shown below.. so whenever i click an anchor tag having href="#id" it redirecting to home page... is there any solution for this abnormal behaviour??

```
UIRouterModule.forRoot({
      states: APP_STATES,
      useHash: true,
      otherwise: { state: 'home' },
      config: routerConfigFn,
      deferIntercept: true,
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

please see if this helps [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)
or [this navigation option](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#!#fragment-anchor)