# Angular: Using anchor tags in innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, angular, anchor

I try to use an anchor tag in my innerHTML by angular using

```
<div>
   <span [innerHTML]="html | safeHtml: 'html'"></span>
</div>
```

where the html contains a string with an anchor say 'Example headline'.

When clicking on the link does not jump to example section instead it redirects to my route /

How can I do that using anchor tag in innerHTML  ?

NOTE : The safeHtml pipe is defines as

```
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
        case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
        case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
        case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
        case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
        default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's related to `innerHTML`. Are you using "Hash Location Strategy"? If so, please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor

Comment: no i am not using hash location strategy