# How to make sure ngAfterViewInit runs after a certain HTML element is rendered?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

In HTML, there is a `<a>` that redirects to another component, and after that scrolls to a certain anchor.

In the target component, I have the following code

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      const elmntLoc: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(fragment);
      window.scroll({
        top: elmntLoc.offsetTop,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    });
  }
```

However, I found that `document.getElementById(fragment);` is always `null`, because this element is displayed conditionally using `ngIf = booleanVariable`, and when this `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook runs, this `booleanVariable` is not calculated yet.

I am wondering how to make sure `ngAfterViewInit` runs after `booleanVariable` is calculated and therefore this element is rendered?

I tried to use `setTime` but it seems hacky...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should run this piece of code after whenever you calculate `booleanVariable`, instead of wanting to change the behaviour of a lifecycle hook. Also, use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) instead of accessing the DOM directly in angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but they don't work properly I am afraid...
(Perhaps I tried them in a wrong way.)

I managed to solve this problem using

```
  @ViewChild('elementId') set elementName(elementName: ElementRef) {
      # code to scroll to a certain section of the page.
  };
```

The method will run **after** this `ViewChild` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using _elementRef instead:

```
this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#'+fragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try waiting for the next animation frame to give a chance for the html element to render.

```typescript
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => {
      const elmntLoc: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(fragment);
      window.scroll({
        top: elmntLoc.offsetTop,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Need to see more of your code to give a more robust answer.