# HTML local linking not working when combined with ng-view

Tags: ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

In my front end I have a simple index.html that I have placed a ng-view tag in it as follows:

```
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <ng-view> <ng-view/>
    </div>
```

---

My routes.js file is something like this:

```
(function() {
angular.module('mainApp')              
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/startbootstrap-landing-page/home.html"
        });
        $routeProvider.when("/products", {
            templateUrl: "/views/products.html"
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
```

})();

When I enter "mywebsite.com/index.html#/" based on the routing in routes.js it will load "/startbootstrap-landing-page/home.html" in the div tag where ng-view is placed. So everything works perfectly till here. But the problem is I have used local addressing/linking tags inside the home.html that they stop working once I load the home.html partial view inside the ng-view div tag. For example I have used something like this in my home.html partial view:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li>
             <a href="#about">About</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#services">Services</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
         </li>
  </ul>
```

So when I click on for example "Contact" it has to jump to the bottom of my designed page where I have used a tag such as this:

```
<a name="contact"></a>
```

.
   .
   .

### But it does not.

The home.html page works perfectly with its local # addressing/linking when used as a standalone html file with html and body tags but its local linking functionality wont work anymore when used as a partial view loaded inside the ng-view tag. Any ideas as to why this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think angular is taking control of the # based urls... have you tried `$anchorScroll`?

[How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

Regards

Comment: Thanks david, but it did not work. However I like to know why this is happening? Any ideas?