# AngularJS Anchor click not working second time

Tags: angularjs, anchor

here is my [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GArzH9gTQCd0r53WhuWO?p=preview)

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
        console.log("called routeChangeSuccess");
        if ($location.hash()) $anchorScroll();
      });
    });
```

1. Click on **go to end of one** it will navigate to the div with the id
2. Second time click on the same link it wont do anything

What i am doing wrong? or is this something to do with angular ?

Note: hack for this would be to use click event and this should work am looking for direct solutions

using angular and route version 1.5.5

*added Bounty

Comment: please check the answer posted. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your plunkr, I noticed that **you were not specifying the route**, when giving the anchor tag, thus the '$routeChangeSuccess' isn't triggered, when I change the particular line to this

```
<a href="/one/#one"> go to end of one </a>
```

I anchor scroll works properly.

**Solution:** [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/keO12ymQfATuxUiabJ7U?p=preview)

Please note the challenges of HTML5 mode in routing, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode), if you have not already taken this into account.

Comment: Spot On.. How do we handle this in case if we have the <a href  in the master page where i have content in different partial views... my route is dynamic for this href

Comment: @Peru Check this link for a multiple views [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0e3LNEUzwXMZmaPUaRV?p=preview) for different views. For different partial views check this link [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0q2NFYFbmHUEfCdyYwv?p=preview)

Comment: it does help.. you got the bounty

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to trigger the `anchorscroll()` on `locationchange` . For this you don't need to check for the `$routeChangeSuccess` . you can directly use the `$locationChangeStart`

```
           $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
                          $anchorScroll();
                 });
```

In order to work with both `$routeChangeSuccess` or `$locationChangeStart` you need to specify the routename to the `anchor` tag as follows

```
<a href="/one/#one"> go to end of one </a>
```

Updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/otQreOLybCzUHoGVHEdq)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <head>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
       <base href="/"/>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <a ng-click="goTo('#one')" > go to end of one </a>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div id="one">
      This is one.
    </div>
      <div ng-view></div>

      <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
          //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
          // $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
          //   console.log("called routeChangeSuccess");
          //   if ($location.hash()) $anchorScroll();
          // });
          $rootScope.goTo = function(value){
            $location.hash(value);
          };
        });
        app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
              templateUrl: "/one.html"
            })
            .when("/one", {
              templateUrl: "/one.html"
            });
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        });
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No i don't want to use click event

Comment: The problem is that you scroll down only when location is changed, but in your case it is not, because you always go to #one. Here is [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uw5r4PVX9DErM4HYM87H?p=preview). You need use click event to get what you want or put some uuid to the url to guarantee inequality.

Comment: @slesh this wont work either if you click on same link twice. if you change route there is no issues is expected

Comment: Yeah, it's key point. You need change route - try to append some dynamic hash, like current time stamp. It should work.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this key point? I don't think that's right way to have timestamp ids