# Opening URL with an anchor (#) in a new window/tab (angularjs with angular-ui router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a link to another page that uses an anchor with ui-sref:

```
`<a ui-sref="details({'id': '12345', '#': 'parts'})" target="_blank">
    to parts
</a>`
```

When the link is opened in the same window (without the `target="_blank"`), it works flawlessly, so it is correctly handled by the stateProvider.
But when opening in a new window (`target="_blank"`), the anchor tag is ignored. The page is opened at the bottom, as if the anchor was not there - the page does not scroll to the fragment specified by the fragment identifier

Can I configure my state so that URLs with anchors are handled correctly? Something like:

```
function runsConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('details', {
        url: '/details?id?#parts', // <-- add the anchor in the url definition? 
        ...
    })
```

But that does not work... It feels to me that this has been solved before, but I can't seem to find a hint on how to do it.

**Edit**

As @georgeawg and @Jonathan-Brizio suggested (thank you!!!) I have to trigger the scoll event myself at the right time, probably due to some embedded components that take a while to render. Why it works when opening the page in the same tab is beyond me.

Here is what did the trick:

```
vm.$onInit = function()
{
    $timeout($anchorScroll); 
};
```

Due to the missing wait time argument, the $anchorScroll is executed immediately when the components are rendered (`$postLink()` was still too early).

Again, thank you @georgeawg and @Jonathan-Brizio for helping out

Comment: When you say that it behaves as if the "anchor is not there", do you mean it doesn't scroll to the fragment specified by the fragment identifier?

Comment: The page of destination have that ID somewhere?

Comment: @georgeawg yes, exactly. Thank you for the comment, I have updated the description

Comment: @JonathanBrizio yes, it is an 'id' attribute on a div. It works when opening the link in the same page

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717011/2220962 You need to implement `$anchorScroll()` in your code!