# Use Bootstrap navbar in angularJs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to use bootstrap navbar in my Angular template but can't get it work !

Actually, Angular considers `href` that permits to get to the corresponding Div as a route and tries to go to its page.

Here is the code I am using :

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found a similar issue on SO ([Anchor links in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026537/anchor-links-in-angularjs))  but the solution suggested didn't work for me.

I saw also that Angular-Ui tabs that does the same thing but in my case, I want to get data dynamically through an Ajax call and that when a Tab is clicked. Unfortunately, Angular-UI tab doesn't seem to have this behavior.

Thank you for your help