# Use anchor link inside angularjs website

Tags: angularjs

I'm using http://localhost/gest.html#!/?COM_ID=6209 link to pass param to angulajs website.
My problem is the use of link anchor inside that page.
Infact if i link to href="#link" to id="link" the link dont work!
Some solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anchor links in Angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026537/anchor-links-in-angularjs)

Comment: I'm not sure how you missed that when searching, or why the question creation screen didn't warn you that you were creating a question with a virtually identical subject line.